# when is the Trimurti referred to first?

Tags: trinity

The concept of Brahma as Creator, Vishnu as preserver and Siva as destroyer seems to be a Puranic concept.  By definition Trimurti cannot appear in Rig Veda since Siva as a God's name does not appear in Rig Veda.

Comment: "since Siva is only known as Rudra in Rig Veda." Wrong notion. There are [many names](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/13650/5212) of him.  Rig Veda is not the only Veda.  There are three more vedas.

Comment: You should learn English and logic..  Something in other vedas does not contradict a statement about rig veda.

Comment: You should read the links I provided before asking someone to learn English.

Comment: Well before and after learning english people interested in Vedas should learn Sanskrit!

Answer (score 3):

> It seems to be a puranic concept

No.

Here they are mentioned in narayana suktam-

> tasyāḥ śikhāyā madhye paramātmā vyavasthitaḥ, sa brahma sa śivaḥ sa
>   hariḥ sendraḥ so'kṣaraḥ paramaḥ svarāṭ.
>
> In the middle of that Flame, the Supreme Self dwells. This (Self) is
>   Brahma (the Creator), Siva (the Destroyer), Hari (the Protector),
>   Indra (the Ruler), the Imperishable, the Absolute, the Autonomous
>   Being.

They are not mentioned in rig Veda because one may confuse the rudra and vishnu (vamana) of 33 gods with shiva the supreme rudra and Vishnu from the trinity with the dwarf which many indologists tend to do.

Comment: Is this from the minor Upanishad called Mahanrayana? If not then in which Veda s it found?

Comment: @Rickross https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narayana_sukta it's found in taittriya aranyaka of yajurVeda but it is a revealed mantra.

Comment: This doesn't talk about the three Gods as creator, preserver and destroyer.

Comment: It's also there in the Mahanarayana. I checked the book. There it's called the "Viswa Purusha Narayana suktam". I asked because I had doubt that it isn't from Vedic Samhitas. BUt Sk is right too, ur refrence isn't proving anything regarding the existence of the concept of Trimurti in the Vedas. Because those things in the brackets like "The Creator" , "The Destroyer" etc are added by the translator. They are not found in the original verses. @Anisha