# Does RgVeda support the view that Brahma, Vishnu, and Mahesh are names of the same Brahman the Absolute?

Tags: rig-veda, brahman, brahmastra, kavacha, pashupatastra

Why should **Brahman** the **Absolute** love to be called by ***three***, and ***only*** three, different names? Do they Really love to be called so? Are Brahma, Vishnu & Mahesh names of the same God? Why should **God** the **Almighty** need, like silly, benighted ***humans***, weapons (**Brahmastra**, **Pashupatastra**, etc.), armours (**Shiva-Kavacha**), shields (**Srivatsa**), etc.? Does **RgVeda** Really ***support*** the ***view*** that Brahma, Vishnu, and Mahesh are names of the same entity?

Comment: Ekam sat vipra bahuda vadanti

Comment: Vivikta ji, an elaboration please !

Answer (score 3):

The concept of Trimūrti in specific-explicit reference to Brahmā, Viṣṇu, & Maheśa (Śhiva) is not stated explicitly in the Ṛg-Veda, **i.e., the three deities which are discussed together as an "equivalent-triad" in detail, in the Paurāṇika-literature, are not discussed together as the *tri-devas* of the Trimūrti godhead, in any major Ṛg-Vedic Literature and definitely not in the saṃhitās.**

This has been discussed in [this QnA](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27017/when-is-the-trimurti-referred-to-first), and minorly explained in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/40911/are-shiva-vishnu-and-brahma-non-vedic-gods/40912#40912)

So basically, the question:

> “*Does Ṛg-Veda support the view that Brahmā, Viṣṇu, & Maheśa (Śhiva), are names of the same Brahman - the Absolute?*”

This question finds no ground to even have a proper answer.

However, in its broadest spirit, the  Ṛg-Vedic Saṃhitā gives even a larger Umbrella of what constitutes the Supreme & Absolute Brahman as follows:

> ##### Ṛg-Veda 1.164.46
>
> इन्द्रं॑ मि॒त्रं वरु॑णम॒ग्निमा॑हु॒रथो॑ दि॒व्यः स सु॑प॒र्णो ग॒रुत्मा॑न् ।
>  एकं॒ सद्विप्रा॑ बहु॒धा व॑दन्त्य॒ग्निं य॒मं मा॑त॒रिश्वा॑नमाहुः ॥४६॥
>
> índram mitrám váruṇam agním āhuḥ átho␣íti divyáḥ sáḥ su-parṇáḥ garútmān |
> ékam sát víprāḥ bahudhā vadanti agním yamám mātaríśvānam āhuḥ || 46 ||
>
> > Indra, Mitra, Varuṇa, Agni, they say about, Even then he is the divine
> > Suparna, the Garutmān. **One is the reality, which inspired-wise ones speak of
> > variously,** They speak about Agni, Yama, Mātariśvan.

Śhrī Aurobindo Ghose gives the [following notes](http://sri-aurobindo.in/workings/matherials/rigveda/01/rigveda_1_eng.pdf) on the same verse:

> > 46. (a).
> >     **It is the one Existent to whom the seers give different names**, Indra,
> >     Matarishwan, Agni, etc. 
> >      <sup>[4. Source № 208. July 1915]</sup>
> > 47. (b).
> >      **The Existent is One, but the sages express It variously**; they say Indra, Varuna, Mitra, Agni; they call It Agni, Yama, Matarishwan.
> >      <sup>[5. Source № 261. January 1915]</sup>

##### Therefore, the Ṛg-Veda very much supports the idea that the Supreme Brahman manifests in myriad forms, which even if not explicitly stated, also represents the Trimūrti deities - Brahmā, Viṣṇu, & Maheśa (Śhiva).

For a traditional interpretation of the Verse by Yāskācārya & Sāyaṇācārya see [this QnA](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/30012/how-have-traditional-vedic-commentators-intepreted-rig-veda-1-164-46). The basic gist of the interpretation even though then, will still remain the same as explained above.

Comment: Do the ' myriad forms ' include plants & trees, floods, tornados, tsunamis, earthquakes, volcanic erupotions, nukes, matter, antimatter, dark matter, dark energy, stars, planets, meteors, comets, nebulas, black holes, galaxies, etc. too ?

Comment: I think, In my humble opinion, whatever you have asked in your question has been very clearly answered in my answer. Therefore, first, I'd suggest you to please Accept and Upvote the answer. I see from your profile you ask several questions but don't even Upvote them, let alone accepting the answer. Please do the needful in this answer and possibly in the other QnAs too

Comment: Secondly, to your follow up question, YES, Brahman encompasses everything. For instance, the great devotee Prahlada when eulogizes Vishnu in the form of Brahman he says the following: पक्षिणः स्थावराश्चैव पिपीलिकसरीसृपाः।
भूम्यापोऽग्निर्नभो वायुः शब्दः स्पर्शस्तथा रसः ॥५॥
रूपं गन्धो मनो बुद्धिरात्मा कालस्तथा गुणाः।
एतेषां परमार्थश्च सर्वमेतत्त्वमच्युत ॥६॥, which basically is saying whatever your have asked - *"do 'Myriad Form' include x, y, z, tom, uck, harry, et al."* - Yes Brahman encompasses everything.

Comment: But, my dear Palpatine, those sages Really did Not have any idea of gravity, magnetism,  electrons, protons, neutrons, atoms, molecules, matter, antimatter, dark matter, dark energy, stars, planets, nebulas, black holes, galaxies, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Not only Brahma, Vishnu, Shiva, all the deities in vedas are names of same Parabrahma.

> **Rigveda 1:164:46.** They call him Indra, Mitra, Varuna, Agni, and he is heavenly nobly-winged Garutman. **To what is One, sages give many a title they call it Agni, Yama, Matarisvan.**

The same thing is said in other vedas.

> **Yajurveda 32:1.** AGNI is That; the Sun is That; Vâyu and Chandramâs are That. The Bright is That; Brahma is That, those Waters, that Prajâpati.

> **Atharvaveda 9:10:28.** They call him Indra, Mitra, Varuna, Agni; and he is heavenly nobly-winged Garutmān. **That which is One bards call by many a title: they call It Agni, Yama, Mātariswan.**

This one is from Upanishads;

> **Shwetashwara Upanishad IV-2:** That Itself is the fire, That is the sun, That is the air, That is the moon, That is also the starry firmament, That is the Brahman, That is the waters, That is Prajapati.

> **Kavialya Upanishad 8.** He is **Brahma**, he is **Siva**, he is Indra. He is the imperishable, supreme self illumined Lord. He alone is **Vishnu**. He is the life giving breath. He is time, he is fire, and also the moon.

Comment: OP asks specifically from the Rig-Veda. Other references from other Vedas or Upanishads are not needed in the answer.

Comment: @Vivikta yes. But I thought that it would be better to give some extra refrences.

Comment: Sanatan Darshan, 'Agni' is fire and 'Yama' death ; what is 'Mātariswan' ? And what do ' Indra', 'Mitra',and 'Varuna' stand for ? Curious to know !