# Why vedas were revealed sanskrit?

Tags: vedas

Why did vedas were revealed in sanskrit.

It would be easy if the Vedas were revealed in a different and easier language.

Comment: This is untrue. Vedas were revealed in a supernatural form

Comment: @Carmensandiego vedas were revealed in sanskrit. According to mimamsa and Vedanta vedas are authorless. And according to Nyaya God revealed vedas

Comment: Not correct. Drashtas didnt get mantara darshanas in as text,  sound etc. Mantaras had super physical form

Comment: @Carmensandiego so did we get the knowledge of the Vedas.

Comment: Seems like a dup of https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15134/why-did-they-invent-sanskrit-as-veda-language-not-any-other-script, please search for similar questions before asking new ones on the same topic.

Comment: @sv there is no answer to it. The one answer is deleted

Comment: I know, but still a dup. Another similar question: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/13952/the-mysterious-origin-of-the-divine-sanskrit-language. Better to search for similar questions before asking.

Comment: if there were revealed in any other 'language', you would ask the same question 'why they were revealed in Bengali, why not French, or why French why not UngaBunga'