When did the specific proper features and characteristics of Lord Vishnu and Lord Shiva start appearing in the Hindu literature?
Note: This is a research question.
By specifc proper features and characteristics I mean Niravakasha Linga.
My question is when did atleast a couple of the Niravakasha Lingas listed below, of Lord Vishnu and Lord Shiva start appearing in Vedic literature?
The main purpose of this question is to understand when the currently known forms of Lord Shiva and Lord Vishnu came into practice in Vedic Hinduism, as there is some scholarly consensus that Vedic Rudra and Vedic Vishnu were quite different to the currently known forms of Lord Shiva and Lord Vishnu and that slowly over a period of time these two deities gained prominence in orthodox Vedic community. So by knowing when the currently known forms were first described we can understand when along the development of Vedic literature, Lord Shiva and Lord Vishnu rose in prominence.

Vedic literature is probably of the following choronological order
Vedas

Rig Veda
Yajur Veda
Sama Veda
Atharvana Veda

Mukhya Upanishads

Chandogya Upanishad
Brihadaranyaka Upanishad
Taittiriya Upanishad
Aitareya Upanishad
Kaushitaki Upanishad
Kena Upanishad
Isha Upanishad
Svetasvatara Upanishad
Mundaka Upanishad
Katha Upanishad
Prashna Upanishad
Mandukya Upanishad
Maitri Upanishad


Lord Vishnu Niravakasha Lingas:

Residing in Vaikunta
Sleeping on Shesha
Sleeping in Milk ocean
Garuda vahana, Garuda Flag
Holding Shanka Charka Gadha Padma
Association with Shargna Bow and Nandaka Sword
Four Arms and Bluish body
Husband of "Lakshmi" (Please do not refer to the word Shri as it is more generic word for wealth)
Srivatsa mark and Kaustubha Jewel
Association with Kamala
Association with Tulsi
Reference to any Dashavatara forms and Puranic stories of Lord Vishnu along with atleast one other Niravakasha linga.

Note: Please don't consider the following lingas for citations. These characteristics can be there along with the above mentioned characteristics, but these characteristics alone may not be sufficient.

Description of Lord of Shri in Purusha Sukta as it is very generic: it could just mean lord of all wealth, describing the opulence of the God
Usage of the word Vishnu
Usage of the word Upendra
The description of measuring the Universe in three strides


Lord Shiva Niravakasha Lingas:

Residing in Kailasa
Vrushaba vahana, Vrushaba Flag
Holding Trishula and Damaru
Association with Pinaka bow
Wearing Cresent Moon on head
Wearing Ganga on head
Husband of "Uma" or "Parvathi"
Father of Lord Ganesh and Lord Subramanya.
Using Snakes as ornaments.
Blue throat
Association with Bhootas and Ganas
Lord of Animals - Pashupathi
Association with Bilva and Rudraksh beads
Reference to any Puranic stories of Lord Shiva along with atleast one other Niravakasha linga

Note: Please don't consider the following lingas for citations. These characteristics can be there along with the above mentioned characteristics, but these characteristics alone may not be sufficient.

Usage of the word Rudra
Three eyes
Using animal skin (of tiger, elephant or deer) as cloth


Edit: Since this question is  causing confusion, let me clarify it.
My question is not, when did all this characteristics first appear, my question is when did atleast two proper characteristics appear for the first time. So the answer, even though requires lots of research, is quite a short answer. It will be a couple of shlokas with Niravakasha lingas from Vedic scriptures.

This is a highly loaded question. You have to understand that many people across time have spend years scanning the evolution of Vedic Divinities till date. Curtain you question to its shortest.

@SanatanaDhara loaded?? Means??

@SanatanaDhara I'm not asking about the evolution, I'm asking when did particular forms first come up in Vedic literature.

In my opinion, this is like 26 questions (one question for each characteristic) compressed into one. It requires lot of effort to answer this in detail.

@estimator No, I think I should explain better. My question is not when did all this characteristics first appear, my question is when did any one or two characteristics appear for the first time. So its more like 2 questions questions jammed into one.

How can one get the origin of these attributes of Śiva viz. Umāpati, Paśupati, Tryambaka, resident of mountain etc. without any reference to Rudra? It's simply absurd

@Śipiviṣṭa I'm not telling Rudra should not be there. I'm telling only Rudra should not be there.

@HariKumar if you are saying you are in research then you should start reading university papers, or direct translations. However here is a link that suits your need https://namahshivaya.net/

@SanatanaDhara thank you

@Śipiviṣṭa https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/59267/29862

Niravakasha Lingas Of Lord Shiva in the Vedas.
Shloka 1 - Krishna Yajurveda's Taittiriya Aranyaka

नमो हिरण्यबाहवे हिरण्यवर्णाय हिरण्यरूपाय हिरण्यपतयेऽम्बिकापतय
उमापतये
पशुपतये॑ नमो॒ नमः ॥ ०। १०। २२। ४०॥ ॥ २२॥

Niravakasha Lingas Used:

Ambika Pathi - Lord of Ambika
Uma Pathi - Lord of Uma
Pashupathi - Lord of animals


Shloka 2: Shree Rudram (Krishna Yajurveda's Taittiriya Samhita)

नमस्ते अस्तु भगवन् विश्वेश्वराय महादेवाय त्र्यंबकाय
त्रिपुरान्तकाय त्रिकाग्निकालाय कालाग्निरुद्राय  var  त्रिकालाग्नि
नीलकण्ठाय म्रुत्युंजयाय सर्वेश्वराय
सदाशिवाय श्रीमन्महादेवाय नमः ॥ २०॥

Niravakasha Lingas Used:

Tripruantaka - Destroyer of three cities
Neelakanta - Blue throated one


Shloka 3: Shree Rudram (Krishna Yajurveda's Taittiriya Samhita)

नमो भवाय च रुद्राय च नमः शर्वाय च पशुपतये च
नमो नीलग्रीवाय च शितिकण्ठाय च
नमः कपर्दिने च व्युप्तकेशाय च
नमः सहस्राक्षाय च शतधन्वने च
नमो गिरिशाय च शिपिविष्टाय च
नमो मीढुष्टमाय चेषुमते च नमो ह्रस्वाय च वामनाय च
नमो बृहते च वर्षीयसे च
नमो वृद्धाय च संवृद्ध्वने च ॥ ५१॥

Niravakasha Lingas Used:

Pashupati - Lord of animals
Neelagreeva - Blue necked one
Shitikanta - Bluish black throated one
Girishayi - One who sleeps on top of mountain


Thanks to @savdy for this answer, which was used as a reference.

The Three steps of Lord Vishnu's Vamana avatara is a famous purANic story. But Lord Vishnu's three steps are mentioned in a more generic sense in the Rig Veda at many places, for example, 1.154.1-2-

viṣṇornu kaṃ vīryāṇi pra vocaṃ yaḥ pārthivāni vimamerajāṃsi |
yo askabhāyaduttaraṃ sadhasthaṃ vicakramāṇastredhorughāyaḥ ||
pra tad viṣṇu stavate vīryeṇa mṛgho na bhīmaḥ kucaro ghiriṣṭhāḥ |
yasyoruṣu triṣu vikramaṇeṣvadhikṣiyanti bhuvanāni viśvā ||


Now shall I proclaim the heroic deeds of Viṣṇu, who measured out the earthly realms, who propped up the higher seat, having stridden out three times, the wide-ranging one. 2. In this way Viṣṇu will be praised for his heroic deed—(he who is) like a fearsome wild beast, living in the mountains and roaming wherever it wants, in whose three wide strides dwell all living beings.

The Three eyes of Lord Shiva is mentioned in Rig Veda 7.59.12 -

tryámbakaṃ yajāmahe sugandhíṃ puṣṭi-vardhánam
urvārukam íva bandhánān mṛtyor mukṣīya mā 'mṛtā́t


We sacrifice to Tryambaka (one with three eyes) the fragrant, increaser of prosperity.
Like a cucumber from its stem, might I be freed from death, not from deathlessness.

Note: Translations by Stephanie W. Jamison and Joel P. Brereton

Thank you for your answer, but measuring universe with three strides doesn't fit the criteria as there is speculation that it was first the characteristic of the Vedic diety Vishnu which was later adapted to Vamana avatara. And regarding Three eyes, it is good, but it only is one linga, does previous or next shloka has any other linga? It would be better if atleast two lingas are present.

This is the problem with using only one Niravakasha Linga https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/21500
