# What is Vedic Dharma? and what is the origin of Vedas?

Tags: vedas

What is Dharma according to the sruti literature? 
How was Vedas composed? who is the first rishi? and how was it compiled? there seems to be 300 rishis who wrote mantras..how were they collected over time?
Please explain it only from authority of sruti, not smriti.

Comment: See my answer here about eternal nature of Vedic religion: http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/270/should-we-change-the-community-name-to-sanatan-dharma/632#632 and Vedas were preserved by this method: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9517/procedures-used-for-preserving-the-integrity-of-the-vedas/13703#13703

Comment: It is impossible to trace the origin of the mantras / the first rishi.