# Are vedic chanting (swara) only applicable to vedas?

Tags: vedas, stotra, vishnu-sahasranama, vedic-chanting

I came across 'swaras' a few days ago:

1. Are *Swaras* (see this [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/13703/21353) which explains them) only applicable to vedic chants, what about the stotras in *tantric* texts?
2. Also what about *Swaras* of stotras found within *Mahabharata* or *Ramayana*? Same thing for *purana*.

I couldn't find Swaras for *Aditya Hridyam* and *Vishnu Sahasranamam*. If they exist, do post the link for the same.

Comment: Only Vedic language has svaras because the Vedic language is very old and preserved, whereas agamas, puranas, etc. came much later after Panini's time and Sanskrit lost its pitch accent.