# What is meant/represented by the numbers in this Vedic Chant table on Wikipedia?

Tags: vedas, vedic-chanting

I am looking [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedic_chant#Oral_transmission):

[image]

What do these numbers mean in terms of the chanting? I don't follow. Can you provide an example of romanized sanskrit (possibly alongside devanagari) and show what these numbers mean, how to apply the theory in practice?

Comment: 122112... suppose the main mantra is "Your Glory" now Your=1, Glory=2, so it would be read as "Your Glory Glory Your Your Glory... " also see [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9517/procedures-used-for-preserving-the-integrity-of-the-vedas/13703#13703), I've there given example of Ghana patha...

Comment: @Tezz you can post that potion of your answer here :)