# The Anandamaya and the Causal Body

Tags: advaita

Hello … I have two questions that perhaps you can help me with ….
From my understanding, the Anandamaya Kosha forms the Causal Body (Karana-Sarira or Karana-Deha) and we experience Deep/Dreamless Sleep (Sushupthi) in this state (Prajna Avastha). 
1).  Upon Self-realization (Atma-Sakshakara) does the Causal Body [Deha] get “burnt away”? and if so, what happens when a Jivan-Mukti sleeps? ... and because an Avatar is born through His Sankalpa (His Divine Will/Resolve) and not through Karma; I take it that He would not have a Causal Body – is that correct? 
and
2).  Which body [Subtle or Causal] does the Kundalini Shakti belong to?

Comment: I am voting to close as you have many questions in one posting. Limit each posted question to one question. See here also - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7055/where-does-the-four-states-of-consciousness-occurs-in-an-individual/7058#7058 and https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/where-does-a-soul-attach-to-the-body/6787#6787

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does a Soul attach to the Body?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/where-does-a-soul-attach-to-the-body)

Comment: The panchakoshas remain until the yogi chooses to become absorbed union oness with Parabrahman. Tho his consciousness would be beyond panchasharira/koshas.

Comment: Split kundalini and casual body into separate questions. One question per post