# Does every universe has different events?

Tags: universe

Many slokas in [The S'rîmad Devî Bhâgawatam](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/db/index.htm) says that there is an infinite number of universes. Consider the following [excerpt](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/db/bk09ch03.htm) for example:

> Nârâyana said:-- “O Devarsi! ......... **In his every pore countless universes are existing. So much so that even S’ri Krisna could not count them. If it were possible to count the number of dust particles, it is impossible to count the number of universes.** ............;

My doubt is whether the events in every universe is the same? If not, are they same at least at an abstract level (repetition of yugas and avatars of god etc.,)?

Comment: Same question I have. could Ramayana be happening in another Universe now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there Hindu scriptural references for "Simulation hypothesis" or the "theory of simulation"?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20095/are-there-hindu-scriptural-references-for-simulation-hypothesis-or-the-theory) ... The accepted answer suggests that various Indra-s can have their own atomic universe.

Comment: Yes, it is same. You can read purusha sukhtam or know about avyakt/maya or hiranyagarba.