# Do Shakta beliefs explain Hindu cycles of time?

Tags: devi, durga, shakti, shaktism, kali

Hey guys I had to delete my first account, I was the new Shakta one with the vegan puja questions.

My question here is : Are there places in the Shakta texts where cycles of time are explained ?

Like how there is repetition of chaturyugs with sort of similar set of events, but some differences too, obviously. Then each kalp with thousand chaturyugs  will approximately repeat also with some differences of kalp-bhed ?

And then the universe repeats more precisely and accurately all over again, endlessly ?
Eternal return, basically, with the jivas moving through the bodies as per their actions, deeds.

Also, it’s given that Devi shows the gods the huge number of universes with separate deities in charge of them.
Do all the universes then repeat over and over with their own unique mahayug/kalp situation going on ?

It seems like every universe would be different of course, but wouldn’t each of them go through repetitive time cycles ? With everything being karma-based like it is here ? Seems like same rules would apply, right ?

Just wondering if there are any mentions of this, or explanations of this, in the beliefs of Shakta sects. I’m of Shakta faith but very new, I converted recently.

Comment: variations on this question have been asked several times. Your question may be a duplicate. suggest searching this forum for kalpas. The vedas are unclear as to whether there is only this 'universe' or there are 'multi-universes' as it has become referred to now in popular parlance. Chose which one your mind is more comfortable with.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda , There are references in puranas, on Sahasra andas(Cosmic egg) in viraja river, and any normal jiva may not know about other andaas except for the one which they are part of . Subrahmanya Bhujangam (23)sahasrAnda bhokthA tvayA ShooranAmA, hathas tArakas simhavaktrascha dhaitya(Daitya Shoora has ruled several universes/cosmic egg) gives a cue on this.But without a commentary by a sage, its difficult read between the lines , and truly know what it connotes.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Those questions were examined from the Vaishnav viewpoint while I’m looking for the Shakta views on time cycles & repetition in the multiple universes. Also there are so many mentions of multiple numerous universes in Hindu mythology, like that story of Krishna inviting all the Brahmas with enormous numbers of heads, things like that.

Comment: While looking through topics found that same sort of question was posted before : https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29179/does-every-universe-has-different-events?r=SearchResults&s=13%7C25.4296