# Hare Krishna Hare Ram mantra for Vishnu or Supreme God?

Tags: vishnu

The holy verses:

hare kṛiṣhṇa hare kṛiṣhṇa
kṛiṣhṇa kṛiṣhṇa hare hare

hare rāma hare rāma
rāma rāma hare hare

Lord Krishna and Lord Ram were incarnations of Lord Vishnu? So these maha-mantras are for Lord Vishnu or the Supreme God?

Comment: Well, the Hare Krishna Mahamantra is mainly chanted by Gaudiya Vaishnavas, and Gaudiya Vaishnavas believe that Krishna is the supreme god.

Comment: By the way, you may be interested in my question here, relating to the Hare Krishna Mahamantra: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2606/36

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan thank you sir, for giving reference of your question

Comment: Well if you are a devotee of Vishnu, then he is your supreme god and if you are not then Vishnu is the form of supreme god anyways.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Your terminology is slightly imprecise.  Vaishnavas believe that Vishnu is supreme, but not all Vishnu devotees do.  I'm certainly a devotee of Vishnu, Shiva, Ganesha, and many other gods, but I don't think Shiva is the supreme god.  I do think that the supreme God (Vishnu) is the Antaryami or inner self of Shiva, just as he is the Antaryami of the other gods and he is the Antaryami of the soul of every human.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan This is perspective of individuals. Shiva linga represents Shiva-Shakti, Brahma and Vishnu. It is Symbolic represention of Supreme God or Brahman or SADASHIVA (Shaivas call him by SadaShiva). It is the same thing explained differently in different Puranas. Para Vasudeva = Sada Shiva. Shiva is only male energy of Sada Shiva.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan You believe that Shiva is/was a jiva so you cannot be devotee of a jiva.

Comment: @AnilKumar There is no male/female energy. Para Shiva is the highest Shiva in the form of Shambhu, from Shambhu comes Sada Shiva. In any case, Shiva is not different from Sada Shiva. The Shiva with Vasuki around his neck, moon on his head, that is one and only Shiva. It's just different manifestations of the same being. Shiva is Brahman so is Shakti.

Comment: @Chinmay I can definitely be a devotee of a Jiva.  I think that all the Devas (apart from Vishnu) are Jivas, but I am still devoted to them.  Even though they are Jivas, they are Jivas that have achieved an exalted state due to their past actions, and thus they are definitely worthy of our reverence and worship.  In any case, when worshipping other gods, I do keep in mind that Sriman Narayana is their Antaryami, so that when I worship them I also worship him.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria According to Shiva Purana, Shiva and Shakti together is called Shiva-Shakti aka SadaShiva. Shiva you say is Shankara aka Rudra, human manifestation of Shiva. Shiva is formless according to Shiva Purana. I think every story of Hindu Mythology that didn't happen on earth involves allegory. Best example would be Samudra Mathanam.  See [this](http://wingsforall.com/blog/how-shiva-s-damaru-explain-origin-of-indian-vowels-consonants-alphabets-lan/) what **DAMARU** of Shiva could mean. Also His dance (**NATARAJA**) has lot of allegory and scientists are still finding correlation.

Comment: Yes it refers to Lord Rama, who is the Supreme Brahman personified. :) There is no mantra or expression that can describe the formless Brahman. All mantras therefore take an indirect route, i.e. they descibe the indescribable Brahman by giving Him characteristics, (e.g. name Rama Krishna, form Shiva or sound AUM) and then worshipping Him through that. In reality, that Attributeless Brahman cannot be described, He can only be experienced (like sweetness of sugar cannot be described, it can only be experienced). Praying to God with form is not different from meditating on Supreme Brahman. :)

Comment: Yeah, Lord Krishna and Lord Rama were manifestations of Lord Vishnu, and they all (Krishna, Rama, Vishnu) are one and the same Supreme Lord or Supreme God or Brahman usually called *para brahman*, ie Supreme Brahman. Btw, acaryas have also explained that name *rāma* in the *Hare Krishna maha mantra* that you have quoted can refer to Lord Balarama (bala-rāma) also, for He is also the same Lord Vishnu or Supreme God, ie Brahman or the Supreme Absolute Truth (Brahman) of the Upanishads.

Answer (score 3):

Rama and Krishna are the avatars of Lord Vishnu. Devotees of Lord Vishnu believe that Lord Vishnu is the supreme God. So they chant these Maha-mantras. It is based on your belief that to whom you worship and whom you think as supreme.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/8968)

Comment: @VineetMenon Unfortunately this is what happens when new users can't comment.

Comment: @VineetMenon Can we do anything to make new users comment on questions?

Comment: @AnilKumar No. Across SX sites, users with at least 50 rep aren't allowed to comment.

Comment: Can we worship Lord shriram thinking as supreme god or it will be act out of ignorance that Lord Vishnu is supreme god ?

Answer (score 2):

Different people have different beliefs as to who is 'Supreme Lord'.

However; the Mahamantra

**hare kṛiṣhṇa hare kṛiṣhṇa kṛiṣhṇa kṛiṣhṇa hare hare/
hare rāma hare rāma rāma rāma hare hare**

is chanted mostly by the followers of Chaitanya Mahaprabhu(Gaudiya Vaishnavas/ISKCON).
Gaudiya Vaishnavas accept Krishna as the 'Supreme Lord'. There are references to this in [Bhagavat Purana](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/3/28)(Srimad-Bhagawatam), [Brahma Samhita](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bs/5/1) etc.

Also krishna is not considered as mere incarnation but as Supreme lord himself by many of the vaishnavas.

I would also like to add that there is no difference between Vishnu and His expansion. But to carry out different works;Lord has assumed different forms and exhibited only that much of opulence and potency which was required to carry out the particular mission.

**so yes Hare krishna Mahamantra does refer to supreme lord.**

Answer (score 1):

Answer to this question is in mangalacharan of kali santaran upanishad itself. It goes likes this

यद्दिव्यनाम स्मरतां संसारो गोष्पदायते ।

सा नव्यभक्तिर्भवति तद्रामपदमाश्रये ।।1

जिसके स्मरण से यह संसार गोपद के समान अवस्था को प्राप्त हो जाता है, वह ही नव्य (सदा नूतन रहने वाली) भक्ति है, जो भगवान श्रीराम के पद में आश्रय प्रदान करती है ।।

कलिसन्तरणोपनिषद् वेद्यपद तत्त्व स्वरूपकम् ।

पारम ऐश्वर्य विभवं रामचन्द्रपदं भजे ॥2

कलीसंतरण उपनिषद वेदों के सार का अवतार हैं। परम ऐश्वर्य और शक्ति वाले आदिदेव भगवान श्री रामचन्द्र जी का  मैं वन्दना करता हूं।

Mangalacharan refers to original and supreme personality of godhead swaym bhagwan shri Ramchandra.

Answer (score 1):

(कलिसंतरण उपनिषद)

यद्दिव्यनाम स्मरतां संसारो गोष्पदायते ।

सा नव्यभक्तिर्भवति तद्रामपदमाश्रये ।।

जिनके स्मरण मात्र से यह संसार गोपद के समान अवस्था को प्राप्त हो जाता है, उसी को नित्य किशोर रहने वाली भक्ति कहा गया है जो भगवान श्री रामचंद्र के चरणों में आश्रय प्रदान करें।

Comment: Welcome to HSE! Though it is okay to add verse in the respective language, however its translations must be in English.