# When was the earliest that the Gaudiya Vaishnavas reversed the order of "Rama" and "Krishna" in their mantra?

Tags: mantras, gaudiya-vaishnavism

I remember from childhood that you say "Hare Rama" first.

If you know Hindi, you can see the following video where a Sankarachrya talks about it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yVe3SSfJk0g

When did Gaudiya Vaishnavas reverse the order of the Mahamantra?  Do non-sectarian Hindus and non-gaudiyas chant in the traditional order?

Comment: It seems they have reversed it..I personally chant Hare Rama first..But it really doesn't matter because when we chant this mantra several times it becomes cyclic and it's hard to say which word is being chanted first.. - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22774/12304

Comment: not true that the order doen't matter.  they are long sentences and your breathing breaks will tell you which come first.  apparenly it has been done deliberately.

Comment: But linked question mention the fact that as per Kali-Santarana Upanishad, Hare Rama comes first..and as per Gaudiya Vaishnavas, Hare Krishna comes first..so ur question is Duplicate..

Comment: question changed @YDS

Comment: @SK Why not? What's wrong with the term "Mahamantra"?

Comment: it seems to be getting used for self-hypnosis and seem to be something a 3-year old would recite.  something like rudra japam is a mahamantra - it encapsulates the whole of hinduism.

Comment: @YDS hos is it dupe?

Comment: @AnkitSharma - I think answer is already there in Duplicate one

Comment: @SwiftPushkar but question are different

Comment: @SK - Yes most of the people chant the mantra in traditional order. Here in Maharashtra even Vaishnavas do follow traditional order while chanting the mantra ,at the end of ceremonies ,pujas & arati.

Comment: @AnkitSharma It was exact dupe..now OP changed the question..You can check OP's comment "question changed" or Edit history..

Comment: @YDS [first version](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/revisions/23915/1), still not dupe

Comment: @AnkitSharma seriously..did you go through the answers of linked question.. Question title doesn't look dupe but it has answers which mention "as per Kali-Santarana Upanishad, Hare Rama comes first..and as per Gaudiya Vaishnavas, Hare Krishna comes first.." so as per my understanding, original question was Duplicate..

Comment: you are trying to prevent the question from being answered.  Gauidiyas elevate krishna over all Hindu deities and this may be deliberate and may be there is documentaion as to who did it and when @YDS

Comment: @SK nope..ur understanding is not correct about my motive.. Didn't u see my comment, "i personally chant Hare Rama first"..ur first version was dupe but after edit its not..let me remove my dupe vote..

Comment: @YDS question shouldn’t be closed based on answer but question itself

Comment: They have never changed the word order in the mantra as far as I know.