# Relationship between Hare Krishnas and Hindus?

Tags: krishna

Is there any relationship between Hare Krishnas and Hindus, or do these belong to two entirely different religions?

Comment: All orthodox 'Hindus' (more properly 'Vedantists' - which all modern day 'Hindus' are) have 3 things in common - they all believe in God, they all believe in the Vedas as the revealed word of God, and they all believe in cycles. What or Who God is - is the chief distinction between the different sects. Hare Krishnas are a Vashnavite sect. Vashnavites believe that the Supreme Godhead is Krishna (Vishnu).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hare Krishnas are Hindus as they worship Lord Krishna. Krishna is the 8th incarnation of Lord Vishnu(among the major incarnations).

Also,

Hare Krishnas chant the Mahamantra

> "Hare Krishna Hare Krishna Krishna Krishna Hare Hare 
>   Hare Rama Hare Rama Rama Rama Hare Hare:"

Which is from Kali-Santarana Upanishad. Upanishad are part of Vedas. So they follow Vedic religion.

But Hare Krishnas are not the only Hindus. Hare Krishnas believe Lord Krishna to be supreme, Shaivites believe Lord Shiva to be Supreme, Vaisnavas believe Lord Vishnu to be Supreme, Shaktas believe Devi to be Supreme, Ganapatyas believe Lord Ganesh to be Supreme, Suryaties believe Lord Surya (Sun God) to be Supreme, Shankhyas don't believe in God (Prakirti and Purush do all for them) and so on.... But they all are considered Hindus (as they all accept authority of Vedas).

So basically,

> **All Hare Krishnas can be considered Hindus, but all Hindus aren't Hare Krishnas.**

Comment: Thanks, so what is the relationship between Hinduism and Vedas?

Comment: @JackMaddington Vedas are the core religious texts of Hinduism... Samhitas of Vedas contain words heard by sages during meditation... these words are explained in Puranas and other scriptures...

Comment: @JackMaddington read answer here for more details... http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/774/how-did-the-vedas-in-hinduism-come-into-existence

Comment: @Tezz The Kali Santarana Upanishad is widely considered not to be an authentic Upanishad; see here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2606/36

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan but I'm writing answer from their perspective... as they consider it authentic... means they subscribe to Vedanta... ie. they are considered Hindus... it's in their belief... as per their perspective...

Comment: The Hare Krishna maha mantra that you have posted is not correct, it should have one "Krishna" instead one "Hare".