# Why Gaudiya Sampradaya follow Kali-Upanishad?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, mantras, gaudiya-vaishnavism

Why Gaudiya Sampradaye followed the [Kali Upanishad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali-Sa%E1%B9%87%E1%B9%AD%C4%81ra%E1%B9%87a_Upani%E1%B9%A3ad) of Krsna Yajurveda.?

Comment: If you are answering your question please mark it as an answer, so that the percentage of answered questions does not fall down.

Comment: @yogi Yeah,Wish I can, But it shows me you can mark your answer in 2 days .because, I have Limitation.

Comment: Okay, but please remember to mark it later.

Comment: Sure  I will !!!

Comment: By the way, a bigger issue is that I don't think the Kali Santarana Upanishads is even an authentic Upanishad of the Atharvana Veda; see my question here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2606/36

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nitaibol! Gaudiya Vaishnav here. There is no mis-interpretation of the Mantra at all. All the Gaudiya Acharyas, from the time of Lord Chaitanya have quoted the Mahamantra to be:

**"Hare Krsna Hare Krsna, Krsna Krsna Hare Hare, 
Hare Rama Hare Rama, Rama Rama Hare Hare"**

The change to Hare Rama first, was made in recent manuscripts by Ramanandis who wished to give more importance to Lord Rama. Actually, you will see, there are some scholars, like Jagad Guru Ramabhadracharya who despite being a Ramanandi, sings the mantra with "Hare Krsna" first. The oldest surviving manuscript we have of Kali Santarana Upanisad is a 17th century copy with the commentary by the Advaitin scholar Brahmayogin Ramacandrendra Sarasvati. It is only from this copy, that the "Hare Rama" appears first. However I doubt the authenticity of that manuscript because we see already in the 15th Century, people were chanting the Mahamantra in its correct order of "Hare Krsna" first. We know this because Dhyanachandra Goswami, in his Gaura Govindarcana Smarana Paddhati quotes Sanat-Kumar Samhita as follows:

*hare-krsnau dvir avrttau
krsna tadrk tatha hare
hare rama tatha rama
tatha tadrg ghare manuh
hare krsna hare krsna
krsna krsna hare hare
hare rama hare rama
rama rama hare hare*

Meaning:

**The words ‘Hare Krsna’ are to be repeated twice, then ‘Krsna’ and ‘Hare’ are to be repeated separately twice. Similarly, ‘Hare Rama’, ‘Rama’ and ‘Hare’ are also repeated twice. The mantra will thus be – Hare Krsna Hare Krsna Krsna Krsna Hare Hare, Hare Rama Hare Rama Rama Rama Hare Hare.**

This is also the order of the Mahamantra found in scriptures such as Brahmananda Purana, Vayu Purana and also later Chaitanya Upanisad and Ananta Samhita.

It is natural that many people in other sampradayas will consider these references as interpolations . We can also say the same in case of them . We have the references intact from our acharyas who were true vairagis and need no interpolation to prove themselves . The whole world is a witness to their scholarship.

There are instances where Srila Jiva Goswami in his sandarbhas has referred to the scriptural quotes presented by Sri Madhavacharya without actually verifying them . Srila Madhavacharya is our sampradaya acharya . Sri Jiva had faith in the scholarship of Madhavacharya . Similarly our faith in the words of our sampradaya acharyas is intact.

Nowadays many references are lost in time and the world knows very well that only a few percent of the entire vedic texts exists today . So there is no point arguing with sastric  references the acharyas provided 500 years ago . Some might be lost in time but the knowledge is preserved in their books and available to us. This is the importance of knowledge transferred through guru parampara . This is the importance of being connected through a bonafide sampradaya.

Nitaibol!

Comment: Hari bol,I m really glad to see your efforts, but can you cite the source !! Hare Krishna, Narayan Narayan !!#

Comment: @ShreeKrishna. Jaya Nitai! Pranam. All the verses I am quoting are from http://gosai.com/writings/the-maha-mantra. Also, you can find a copy of Dhyanachandra Goswami's Gaura Govindarcana Smarana Paddhati online. Also I am basing my claims on the  Maha-mantrartha Dipika of  Jiva Gosvami,  which seems to predate the 17th Century manuscript. My point is, the Mahamantra has been chanted in this way from the time of Lord Chaitanya (and possibly even before). Many great Vaishnavs have also chanted it in this way and written it as such in their commentaries. I see no reason to say otherwise.