# Are any Sri Vaishnava commentaries of the Isha Upanishad available online?

Tags: sri-vaishnava, translation-request, isha-upanishad, vishishtadvaita

As I discuss in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2826/36), the Isha Upanishad has a special property that other Upanishads don't: it's part of the actual Samhitas of the Vedas, i.e. the part of the Vedas whose verses were heard directly from the gods.  (It's the 40th Adyaya of the Shukla Yajur Veda.) So while other Upanishads are just philosophical teachings designed to clarify the meaning of the Vedic verses, the verses of the Isha Upanishad are of divine origin.

Now proponents of the [Vedanta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedanta) school of Hinduism don't generally write commentaries on the hymns of the Vedic Samhitas, but they make an exception in this case because the Isha Upanishad is still an Upanishad.  The Isha Upanishad is only 18 verses long, but it has been the subject of voluminous commentary.   For instance, [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=VSI1AQAAMAAJ&dq=upanishads%20sankara's%20commentary&pg=PA1#v=onepage&q&f=false) is a commentary by Adi Shankaracharya, a proponent of Advaita Vedanta (a philosophy where the Jivatma or individual soul is identical to Parmatma or the divine soul).  And [here](http://www.dvaita.org/sources/shruti/translation.html) is a commentary by Madhvacharya, proponent of Dvaita Vedanta (a philosophy where Jivatma and Paramatma are totally different).  And [here](http://vedabase.com/en/iso) is even a commentary by Bhaktivedanta Prabhupada, who believes in Chaitanya Mahaprabhu's philosophy of Achintya Bheda Abheda (inconceivable unity and difference between Jivatma and Paramatma).

But my question is, what about the other major school of Vedanta, Visitadvaita Vedanta, the philosophy of the Sri Vaishnava sect of Hinduism (of which I'm a member), according to which Jivatmas are distinct parts of Parmatma but Paramatma extends beyond them?  Are there any Sri Vaishnava commentaries on the Isha Upanishad available online in English?

Ramanujacharya, the figure most prominently associated with Visistadvaita, doesn't seem to have written any commentaries on the Isha Upanishad, but two other Sri Vaishnavas did.  The Sri Vaishnava philosopher Vedanta Desikan wrote a commentary on it, which is there in [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/8189564080) and [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=MXnXAAAAMAAJ&source=gbs_ViewAPI), but is it available online anywhere?  A Sri Vaishnava Acharya named Koora Narayana also wrote a commentary on it, available online [here](https://archive.org/details/isavasyopanisatk00kura) in Sanskrit.  But are there any English translations of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swami Uttamur Veeraraghavacharya has written a commentary in Sanskrit by name **Acharya bhasya tatparya** on Sri Vedanta Desika’s Isayasya Upanishad bhasya. I am not sure whether it is available online.

There is a copy of Isavasya upanishad by Swami Vedanta Desika, translated into english by Dr. K.C. Varadachary and Dr. T.Tatachary, printed by TTD, available online for download [gdurl.com/zZZt/download](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4zy5h3qqpxLdENIUzVPZXRoSUE).

Dr N.S. Anatha Rangachar has written a book by name **Principal Upanishads Vol -1** containing the sanskrit verses of the Upanishads and English translation which is mostly based on the Swami Ranga Ramanuja muni’s (16 th century) commentaries on Upanishads from Srivaishnava perspective. The Principal Upanishads Vol-1 contains Isha, Kena, Katha, prasna, Mundaka, Mandukya, Taittiriya, Mahanarayana, Svetasvatara Upanidhads. Again, not sure whether this available online, but hard copy can be purchased from [Haristore](http://www.haristore.com/).
You can check [here](http://nsa.co.in/) for more details for the Dr N.S.Anatha Ranchar's works and other details.

Comment: "There is a copy of Isavasya upanishad by Swami Vedanta Desika, translated into english and printed by TTD, available online for free download." Do you have a link?

Comment: @Keshav - I have the copy, i can share with you. But, can you tell where i should upload and how?

Comment: You can go to http://drive.google.com, upload the document, click the share button, and it will generate a shareable link you can post.  Or you can just email it to me (lugita15 AT gmail DOT com) and I can upload it on Google Drive and give you the link.  By the way, where did you get it from?

Comment: @Keshav - Uploaded on Google drive and added the link. You can dowload it, i suppose. Thanks

Comment: You need to change the sharing setting.  Currently it's set to private, so only you can access it.  You need to make it such that anyone can view it.

Comment: @Keshav - It says anyone can view. Anyway, i have added you id for view. Let me know, if you have an issue. I will try to email you. Thanks

Comment: OK, thanks, now it works.  You should replace the link in your answer with this one, though, because it allows people to do a direct download: http://gdurl.com/zZZt/download

Comment: By the way, where did you get this document?

Comment: @Keshav - From TTD site. You can also check there are some good books available online on TTD.

Comment: Wow, you're right, it is a great site: http://ebooks.tirumala.org

Answer (score 1):

I found this [link](http://www.exoticindia.com/book/details/five-principal-upanishads-exhaustive-commentary-in-english-on-ishavasya-kena-katha-taittiriya-mundaka-upanishads-with-original-sanskrit-transliteration-translation-exposition-and-annotations-based-on-ramanuja-school-IHG016/) that has a book (but it apparently costs $50!) containing commentaries on five Upanishads, including the Ishopanishad, by a Visitadvaita scholar.

Here is where I found that link from: http://www.hindudharmaforums.com/showthread.php?t=11030.