# Looking for scriptural source that introduce Brahmanas

Tags: scripture, vedas, vyasa, brahmanas

I know about Brahmanas (ब्राह्मण ग्रंथ) as described at [BharatDiscovery](http://bharatdiscovery.org/india/%E0%A4%AC%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%A3_%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF), what they are, how they originated, part of Vedas, association with Samhita, Shakha etc. I mentioned them in some of my posts like [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15508/277), [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14428/277) and [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16340/277). But I'm missing scriptural sources.

Similar problem (with having scriptural source) I had about Vedas, how they came into existence, Vedvyasa's division into four Vedas, and how Shakhas formed etc. But recently when I found that information available from Srimad Bhagvatam (12.6) and when I read, I felt contented/happy as having scriptural source!

Hence, I'm looking for scriptural source that mention or describe:

- What are Brahmanas?
- How are they originated? and their association with Samhitas.
- Inclusion of Aranyaka & Upanishads. (If possible)

Recently we have been having some questions viz. [What are the Vedas technically?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18989/277), [Do the Vedas themselves talk about the jnAna and karma kAnda?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19053/277), [Are Upanishad's really parts of the Vedas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19124/277). Though I've posted one [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19002/277) claiming why to consider Brahmanas part of Vedas, but I think we need scriptural source that introduce Brahmanas.

Comment: I think it would be nice if you add "Vedic source".

Comment: How did they originate?? from Bhagwans sri mukha... because they are apaurusheya as they are part of the shrutis.

Comment: @Yogi only Samhita part is believed to be Shruti.

Comment: @Yogi Only Samhitas are Apaurusheya not Brahmanas and Aranyakas.

Comment: @Pandya So even upanishads are smriti?

Comment: @Yogi I mean only Samhita is the hynms heard by ancient Rishis in Tapasya as mentioned [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/781/277).

Comment: The division of the vedas was done by Vyasa. He was the one that put them into their various books and divisions. Your question is circular. "What is the scriptural source for scriptures?" is not logical.

Comment: @Pandya I think there are some sources which are mentioning "What are Brahmanas" below the article you posted. e.g.  ब्राह्मणं नाम कर्मणस्तन्मन्त्राणां च व्याख्यानग्रन्थ:। भत्तभास्कर, तैत्तिरीय संहिता 1.5.1 पर भाष्य.