# How many Brahmanas and Aranyakas are there in the Vedas?

Tags: vedas, translation-request, brahmanas, aranyaka

I know about the four Samhita texts and the later Upanishad texts. However, each Veda has Samhita, Brahmana, Aranyaka and Upanishad.

How many Brahmanas and Aranyakas are there under each Veda?

What are there names? (I just know few names like - Satapath Brahmana, Aitareya Brahmana, Aitareya Aranayaka and Sankhayana Aranyaka).

Can anybody give a full list?

English translation available or not? If available, where from I can get?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6807/36), each of the four Vedas comes in multiple Shakhas or recensions. Each Shakha has its own Samhita, Brahmana, Aranyaka, and Upanishad.  According to Patanjali's Mahabhashya, there were originally 1131 Shakhas, so there were 1131 Brahmanas and 1131 Aranyakas.  But most Shakhas are now lost.  Let me enumerate the surviving Shakhas of the Vedas along with their Brahmanas and Aranyakas:

1. **Rig Veda**: The Rig Veda has two surviving Shakhas, the Sakala Shakha and the Bashkala Shakha.  The Sakala Shakha contains the Aitareya Brahmana and the Aitareya Aranyaka, and you can read them in English in [this document](https://archive.org/details/rigvedacomplete) I created. The Bashkala Shakha contains the Kaushitaki Brahmana, which you can read in English [here](https://archive.org/details/rigvedabrahmana00keitgoog), and the Shankhayana Aranyaka, which you can read [here](https://archive.org/details/sankhayanaaranya015788mbp).
2. **Yajur Veda**: As I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14237/36), the Yajur Veda comes in two forms, Shukla or white and Krishna or black.  The Shukla Yajur Veda has two surviving Shakhas, the Madhyandina Shakha and the Kanva Shakha. The Madhyandina Shakha contains one version of the Shatapatha Brahmana and one version of the Brihad Aranyaka, and you can read them in English [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbr/index.htm). The Kanva Shakha contains another version of the Shatapatha Brahmana and another version of the Brihad Aranyaka, and you can read them in [this document](https://archive.org/details/yajurvedacomplete) I created. The Krishna Yajur Veda has three surviving Shakhas: the Taittiriya Shakha, the Maitrayaniya Shakha, and the Kathaka Shakha.  None of the Brahmanas or Aranyakas of the Krishna Yajur Veda are available online in English, but there are English translations of Taittiriya Brahmana and Taittiriya Aranyaka by R.L. Kashyap available in print form.
3. **Sama Veda**: The Sama Veda has three surviving Shakhas: the Kauthuma Shakha, the Ranayaniya Shakha, and the Jaiminiya Shakha.  There's only one Brahmana of the Sama Veda available in English, the Panchavimsha Brahmana of the Kauthuma Shakha which you can read [here](https://archive.org/details/pancavimsabrahma032052mbp).  And there's only one Aranyaka available in English, the Jaiminiya Upanishad Brahmana of the Jaiminiya Shakha, which you can read [here](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.38101).
4. **Atharvana Veda**: The Atharvana Veda has two surviving Shakhas, the Shaunaka Shakha and the Pippalada Shakha. Most of the Brahmanas and Aranyakas of the Atharvana Veda are lost, which might be for the best considering how Kali Yuga people might misuse it, but one Brahmana survives, the Gopatha Brahmana of the Shaunaka Shakha.  But it hasn't been translated into English.

Whew!

Comment: Is there any information about division of Shakhas available in Brahmanas?

Comment: [Gopatha Brahmana](https://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/handle/10603/151631) actually has been translated into English. You should add this to your answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Vedic Sanskrit corpus**

The corpus of Vedic Sanskrit
texts includes:

**The Samhitas** (Sanskrit
saṃhitā, "collection"), are
collections of metric texts
(" mantras"). There are four
"Vedic" Samhitas: the Rig-
Veda, Sama-Veda , Yajur-Veda ,
and Atharva-Veda , most of
which are available in several
recensions (śākhā ). In some
contexts, the term Veda is
used to refer to these
Samhitas

**The Brahmanas** are prose
texts that comment and
explain the solemn rituals as
well as expound on their
meaning and many connected
themes. Each of the
Brahmanas is associated with
one of the Samhitas or its
recensions. The
Brahmanas may either form
separate texts or can be
partly integrated into the text
of the Samhitas. They may
also include the Aranyakas
and Upanishads.

**The Aranyakas** , "wilderness
texts" or "forest treaties", were
composed by people who
meditated in the woods as
recluses and are the third
part of the Vedas. The texts
contain discussions and
interpretations of ceremonies,
from ritualistic to symbolic
meta-ritualistic points of
view. It is frequently read
in secondary literature.

**Older Mukhya Upanishads**
(Bṛhadāraṇyaka , Chandogya,
Kaṭha, Kena , Aitareya, and
others).

**The Brahmanas, Aranyakas , and
Upanishads , among other things,
interpret and discuss the
Samhitas in philosophical and
metaphorical ways to explore
abstract concepts such as the
Absolute ( Brahman ), and the
soul or the self (Atman ),
introducing Vedanta philosophy,
one of the major trends of later
Hinduism.**

link:— https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedas

There are a lot of brahmanas and aranyakas so you shall get in the following links

[Brahmanas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmana)

[Aranyakas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aranyaka)

Although shatpath brahmana is availablle online on sacred texts.com— http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/