# Immortality of Shiva, Brahma and Vishnu

Tags: shiva, vishnu, brahma, immortality

Is Vishnu only immortal or Shiva and Brahma also are immortal ?
(I know that all afterall are the same, but just for knowing because i read somewhere that only Vishnu is immortal)

Comment: Thank you. But then why do we say that after some million Brahmas some vishnus retire then some shivas retire.means one shiva dies and another becomes shiva. Please explain.

Comment: Who says so? Can you cite your reference please? @Chittaranjan

Comment: Where did you read that Shiva or Vishnu will die?

Answer (score 1):

## Immortality of Shiva

- Atharvashira Upanishad

> ॐ देवा ह वै स्वर्गं लोकमायंस्ते रुद्रमपृच्छन्को भवानिति । सोऽब्रवीदहमेकः प्रथममासं वर्तामि च भविश्यामि च नान्यः कश्चिन्मत्तो व्यतिरिक्त इति । सोऽन्तरादन्तरं प्राविशत् दिशश्चान्तरं प्राविशत् सोऽहं नित्यानित्योऽहं व्यक्ताव्यक्तो ब्रह्माब्रह्माहं प्राञ्चः प्रत्यञ्चोऽहं दक्षिणाञ्च उदञ्चोहं अधश्चोर्ध्वं चाहं दिशश्च प्रतिदिशश्चाहं पुमानपुमान् स्त्रियश्चाहं गायत्र्यहं सावित्र्यहं त्रिष्टुब्जगत्यनुष्टुप् चाहं छन्दोऽहं गार्हपत्यो दक्षिणाग्निराहवनीयोऽहं सत्योऽहं गौरहं गौर्यहमृगहं यजुरहं सामाहमथर्वाङ्गिरसोऽहं ज्येष्ठोऽहं श्रेष्ठोऽहं वरिष्ठोऽहमापोऽहं तेजोऽहं गुह्योहंअरण्योऽहमक्षरमहं क्षरमहं पुष्करमहं पवित्रमहमुग्रं च मध्यं च बहिश्च पुरस्ताज्ज्योतिरित्यहमेव सर्वेभ्यो मामेव स सर्वः समां यो मां वेद स सर्वान्देवान्वेद सर्वांश्च वेदान्साङ्गानपि ब्रह्म ब्राह्मणैश्च गां गोभिर्ब्राह्माणान्ब्राह्मणेन हविर्हविषा आयुरायुषा सत्येन सत्यं धर्मेण धर्मं तर्पयामि स्वेन तेजसा । ततो ह वै ते देवा रुद्रमपृच्छन् ते देवा रुद्रमपश्यन् । ते देवा रुद्रमध्यायन् ततो देवा ऊर्ध्वबाहवो रुद्रं स्तुवन्ति॥१॥
>
> 1. Om. Once upon a time the Devas resorted to the world of Bliss (Kailasa); and the Devas addressed Rudra thus, “who are you?”. He replied: “**I alone was in the beginning; I am now; and will be in the future.** There is none but me.” He spread out himself and pervaded all the quarters. (He said): **“I am eternal**, I am Brahma, I am eastern and western quarters, south and north, up and down, the quarters and cross quarters, I am man and otherwise, woman, I am Gayatri, Savitri, Sarasvati, Trishtup, Jagati, and Anushtup, I am the metre, I am Garhapatya, Dakshina and Ahavaniya fires, I am truth, I am the Cow (the Cow of plenty) Gauri, the first born, superior and best, I am Water and Light, I am the Rik, Yajus, Saman, and Atharvangirasa, I am **imperishable**, I am to be protected and kept in secrecy, I am the forest, I am the lotus (universe), I am pure, top, center, out-side and front, and I am the light which is in ten quarters and otherwise.” I alone exist. All are equal to me. He who knows me knows all the Devas. I nourish the earth through the light of the Sun, (according to a commentator, I perpetuate creation through man and woman), preserve the Brahmins by Brahmanic glory, the oblations by ghee &c, the life by life-giving energy, the truth by truth, and Dharma by Dharma. Next, the Devas did not see Rudra in his own glory. They thought to meditate upon Rudra, and began to praise Him with uplifted hands.

Vedas and Upanishad [says](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/38558/19001) that Brahma, Vishnu and Shiva are different forms of Supereme God so they all are immortal.

Comment: Thank you. But then why do we say that afyer some million Brahmas some vishnus retire then some shivas retire.means one shiva dies and another becomes shiva. Please explain.

Comment: @chittaranjanrout it's a pauranic theory. My answer is based on Upanishads.

Comment: Where did you read that Vishnu or Shiva will retire?