# Who is the Purusha?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, purusha

Who is the Purusha(in Vedas/Purusha Suktam)?

[13:10-13:15](https://youtu.be/MiLo2tD3eCA) says that Lord Shiva is the Purusha.

Are there any contrasting verses?How do Vaishnavas interpret this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Who is the deity of the Purusha Suktam according to different schools?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31798/who-is-the-deity-of-the-purusha-suktam-according-to-different-schools)

Comment: Answers are opinion based, based on the school that the devotee follows.