# What's the story of four vedas?

Tags: vedas, brahma, yuga

Like,

1. Who wrote the vedas?
2. Why four vedas not only one?
3. Whats the need of vedas?
4. How these vedas are useful in this generation?

Comment: As it stands, the question is a partial duplicate of the question linked to above.  If you want to remove the part that's duplicative, and also narrow down your post to a single question, then flag me to reopen it.

Comment: In any case, the reason the Vedas are divided into separate books is so that the people of the Kali Yuga can more easily understand them.  They're divided according to the duties of the different kinds of Yagna priests, like the Hotar, Adhvaryu, etc.; see my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6807/36