# Where is the Sama Veda quote referenced in the Brahma Sutras?

Tags: vedas, philosophy, upanishads, brahma-sutras, sama-veda

As I discuss in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3193/36), by far the most popular school of Hindu philosophy is the Vedanta school, which bases its tenets on the doctrines laid out in the Brahma Sutras, a work by the sage Vyasa which summarizes and systematizes the philosophical teachings of the Upanishads. You can read the Brahma Sutras [here](http://www.advaita.it/library/brahmasutras2.htm). In any case, Adhyaya 3 Pada 3 of the Brahma Sutras describes the Brahmavidyas, 32 lessons found in various Upanishads which can each lead you to Brahman if you meditate upon them. You can see the full list of 32 Vidyas [here](http://ramanuja.org/sri/Web/BrahmaVidya).

But in Adhyaya 3 Pada 3 Sutra 23 of the Brahma Sutras, Vyasa discusses a Vidya that's not included on the standard list of 32:

> Topic-12: Attributes of Brahman in Ranayaniya Not to be Combined Elsewhere 
>   23. And (the attributes of Brahman such as) possession of unchallenged powers and pervasion of heaven are also not to be added to other meditations for the same reason (of association with special abodes).

Now most commentators on the Brahma Sutras agree that these Sutras are about whether a certain Brahmavidya found in the Ranayaniya Shakha of the Sama Veda and should be combined with Brahmavidyas during meditations.  (See my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6807/36) for more information on the Vedic Shakhas.) [Here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sv.htm) is what Adi Shankaracharya says in his commentary on the Brahma Sutras:

> **In the khilas (supplementary writings) of the Rânâyanîyas we meet with a passage, 'Held together are the powers among which Brahman is the best; the best Brahman in the beginning stretched out the sky,'** which mentions certain energies of Brahman, such as holding together its powers, entering into the sky, &c.  And in the Upanishad of the same (i.e. the Rânâyanîyas) we meet with vidyâs of Brahman among which the Sândilya-vidyâ is the first.--The question then arises whether the energies of Brahman just mentioned are to be inserted in those Brahma-vidyâs or not.

The conclusion is that the Brahmavidya found in the "khilas ... of the Ranayaniya" should not be combined with other Bramavidyas, because those other Brahmavidyas deal with meditating on Brahman residing in the heart and the like, as opposed to this one which is about Brahman pervading the sky.  But my question is about where this Brahmavidya is from.

My question is, where in the Ranayaniya Shakha of the Samaveda is the Khila text that this Brahmavidya is from?  For those who don't know, a Khila text is a text found in some versions of a scripture, but not others.  In the context of the Vedas, that means a text found in one Shakha but not others.  (Again, see my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6807/36) for information on Vedic Shakhas.)

So in this case, I assume this Khila text is something found in the Ranayaniya Shakha of the Samaveda but not the Kauthuma Shakha.  Unfortunately, I don't have the Samhita of the Ranayaniya Shakha in Sanskrit, but [this translation](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sv.htm) of the Samaveda Samhita claims to be based on the Ranayaniya Shakha, and it claims that [this translation](https://archive.org/details/translationsanh00stevgoog) is also based on the Ranayaniya Shakha.  But I can't seem to find the Brahmavidya in either one of them.  Perhaps they're in the Brahmana or Aranyaka of the Ranayaniya Shakha (neither of which I have) instead of the Samhita.

If it helps, the line I'm looking for in Sanskrit is "brahma jyestha virya sambhritani brahmagre jyestham divamatatana".  I haven't found this line in the Sama Veda, but I have found this line or close variants of it in other Vedas.
For instance, here is what [verse 2.4.7.10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARjCl.jpg) of the Taittiriya Brahmana of the Yajur Veda says:

> pra sadyo agne atyeshyanyan | 
>   aviryasmai charutaro babhuta | 
>   idenyo vapushyo vibhava | 
>   priyo vishamathithirmanushinam | 
>   **brahma jyestha virya sambhritani |** 
>   **brahmagre jyestham divamatatana |** 
>   ritasya brahma prathamota jajne | 
>   tenarhati brahmana sparditum kah | 
>   brahma srucho ghritavatih | 
>   brahmana svaravo mitah ||
>
> Thou quickly passest by all others, Agni, for him to whom thou hast appeared most lovely, wondrously fair, adorable, effulgent, the guest of men, the darling of the people.
>   **Collected manly powers are topped by Brahma. Brahma at first  spread out the loftiest heaven.** 
>   Brahma was born first of all things existing. Who then is meet to be that Brahma's rival? 
>   Brahma is fatness-dropping scoops: with Brahma was the altar
>      reared. Brahma is worship, lengthened rite, the Rishis who pay sacrifice,
>      the victim's Immolators. Hail!

And here is what [chapter 19 hymn 22](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/av/av19022.htm) of the Atharvana Veda says:

> **bráhmajyeṣṭʰā sámbʰr̥tā viryā̀ṇi bráhmā́gre jyéṣṭʰaṃ dívam ā́ tatāna |**
>   bʰūtā́nāṃ brahmā́ pratʰamótá jajñe ténārhati bráhmaṇā spárdʰituṃ káḥ ||
>
> **Collected manly powers are topped by Brahma. Brahma at first  spread out the loftiest heaven.** 
>   Brahma was born first of all things existing. Who then is meet to be that Brahma's rival?

But does anyone know where this line can be found in the Sama Veda?  I want to see it in its original context, in case there's more to the Brahmavidya than just that one line.