# Why do Brahmins have such surnames?

Tags: vedas, caste-system, name

In Uttar Pradesh Brahmins have common surnames as Chaturvedi alias Chaubey, Dwivedi alias Dubey and Trivedi. Are these surnames which have "Vedi" included in them have something to do with the Vedas. There is common folklore that the Brahmins who know all four Vedas are known as Chaturvedi and those who knew three were called Trivedi and Dwivedi were who knew two Vedas. Is this folklore true if not how did they get such titles?

Comment: yes what u have heard seems correct

Comment: is there any written proof of this in any books

Comment: i am sorry that i dont know.

Comment: The answers to this question cover the surnames: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6802/why-are-brahmins-represented-by-names-of-vedas

Comment: Yes. That is true. In South India we have names like Sastry (who are well versed in Sastras) and Acharyas  (who follow sadhacharas). Generally, Surnames of castes denote their profession in past. You can observe this in other Castes too.

Comment: From [this ch.](http://www.kamakoti.org/hindudharma/part5/chap38.htm) of the book Hindu Dharma: "We had a Trivedi, who was governor of one of our states. Duve and Dave are derived from Dvivedi. One descended from a family well versed in the four Vedas is called a Caturvedin. In Bengal he is called a Catterji. Those who have mastered three Vedas are Trivedins. Today it is rare to see a man who has learned even one Veda, but the fact that members of some families still call themselves Trivedins or Caturvedins show that in the past there must have been individuals who knew more than one Veda."

Comment: @TheDestroyer This is not a duplicate of the other. The other one is very generic and is about Brahmins named after their respective Vedas while this is about being named after the number of Vedas they have mastered. Both are separate.

Comment: Other question is asking about Veda shakhas i.e., rigveda brahmin and Yajurveda brahmin. That is not surname. This is a different question which asks about the origin of surnames in particular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before they became surnames *Dwivedi*, *Trivedi* and *Chaturvedi* were probably titles given to people who have studied more than one Veda. So says Swami Harshananda in [*A Concise Encyclopaedia of Hinduism (Vol. 1)*](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/concise-encyclopaedia-of-hinduism-in-three-volumes-most-comprehensive-and-authoritative-source-on-hinduism-available-today-IDC024/):

> **dvivedī** ('one [who has studied] two Vedas')
>
> Started perhaps as the academic title of a person who has studied two
>   Vedas (dvi = two) it gradually became the family title of persons born
>   as his descendants.
>
> Similarly, the evolution of the two other titles trivedī and
>   caturvedī — for those who are the scions of the persons who had
>   mastered three or four Vedas.
>
> Study of one Veda was the minimum expected of every dvija or the
>   twice-born.

In [*Hindu Dharma: The Universal Way of Life*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/8172760558), Swami Chandrasekarendra Saraswati says the same about the origin of these titles:

> I said that there was no bar on anyone learning more than one śākhā. Even today we find North Indians with appellations like Caturvedī, Trivedī and Dvivedī.
>
> We had a Trivedī, who was governor of one of our states, Duve and Dave are derived from Dvivedī. **One descended from a family well versed in the four Vedas is called a Caturvedin.** In Beṅgāl he is called Catterjī. Those who have mastered three Vedas are Trivedins. Today it is rare to see a man who has learned even one Veda, but the fact that members of some families still call themselves Trivedins or Caturvedins show that in the past here must have been individuals who knew more than one Veda.

Comment: chatterjee comes from chattopadhyay. chatta plus upadhyay is chattopadhyay.Chatta has nothing to do with the four vedas.Chattopadhyay, Bandyopadhyay, Mukhopadhyay and Gangopahyay were made Chatterjee Banerjee Mukherjee and Ganguli most probably by the foreign invaders.

Comment: Guess the swami is wrong about Catterjī then. So it's derived from a village named [Chaṭṭa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chatterjee)? @Pratimaputra

Comment: not known, but highly probable

Comment: Bengal had only Sudras and so there was no one to ritually worship the deities. This situation occurred after the collapse of Buddhism around 1000 ce. So the Pal dynasty imported 5 Brahmin families from Kannauj around 1040 ce. Each one of these families were given 1 village to settle. So Gangopadhyays are derived from one of these families who settled on the bank of Ganga. Local kings also sometimes declared a Sudra family Brahmin in order that they had someone to ritually worship the deities. This is the story I have heard.