# Which scripture provides details about Suka?

Tags: scripture, puranas, saint

I want to learn more about Suka (son of Vyāsa) who narrated Bhagvatam to Parikshit. Which purāna provide details on life or past-life of Suka ?

Comment: Mahabharata has an account of Shuka's life. If you want you'd have to read Mahabharata. For that you need to read it completely because the Shuka's part is little, you cannot attempt to cherry-pick the verses by opening a random chapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many scriptures provide details about Suka, few of them are:

- [Mahabharata: Santi Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12c023.htm)
- [Devi Bhagavatam: Skandha 1](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/db/bk01ch14.htm)
- [Sri Venkatachala - Its Glory](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.162137/page/n302)

---

Related Post(s)

[What scriptures describe Vyasa's son Shuka creating a duplicate of himself?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20945/what-scriptures-describe-vyasas-son-shuka-creating-a-duplicate-of-himself)