# Who is the consumer of our Karmas, if the Atman is merely a silent witness?

Tags: philosophy, karma, atma, rebirth

*Atman* resides in the body as a silent witness and it's not affected (untouched) by anything. Then upon what, our *Karma*s get transmitted to our next lives?
In other words who is the enjoyer/sufferer of our deeds or what is affected (if not *Atman*)?

Comment: Other subtle bodies *Manomaya Sharira* (*Mann* or mind) and *Ananda Sharira* (*Buddhi* or intellect) still remain after the death of *Sthula Sharira* (physical body).  IMO, Former is replaced once the heaven & hell are experienced and latter goes away when liberation(Moksha) happens. Naturally *Sthula Sharira* is given in every birth on earth like planets. While all these is happening for several births, the *Atman* remains as it is (clueless!).

Comment: You are Atma. If you identify yourself with Atma, then you have no more births and have attained Moksha. However if you identify yourself with body, then you have Karma. There are three bodies: 1. Gross or physical body 2. Subtle or astral body (Linga Sarira) 3. Causal body (Karana Sarira). Please refer this answer http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6529/119 for some more info on this. All the best.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between *Buddhi* (बुद्धि) and *Mann* (मन)?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10784/1049)

Comment: The answer to questions such as this one depends on the Hindu school you are asking that question to. Consequently you will get different answers. You may want to specify in your question the point of view of which school you are asking this question.

Comment: Atman is the electricity flow of our physical body. We have "physical body" and "subtle body" which is made up of our wishes and our thinking. Physical body finishes with our death but "subtle body" travels from one birth to other. What we think, we wish and we do, remains in subtle body and that body is responsible for enjoying/suffering in next birth that is related to our past lives.