# What is the difference between Buddhi (बुद्धि) and Mann (मन)?

Tags: vedas, bhagavad-gita, philosophy, atma, mind

I know *Buddhi* (बुद्धि) means intelligence/intellect and *Mann* (मन) means mind. But what is difference between them?

Comment: From mind(Man) intellect(Buddhi) is born.A symbolic representation- Budha graha is regarded as the son of Chandra graha.

Comment: Buddhi is brain power or way of thinking of a person , while mana is a indriya it is cause of all misries, manas is the controller of everything in body , so if we control mana we control our body. Mana is not a physical object but is has physical consequences, e.g. the taste of some food item is experienced through the sensors in tounge but the real experience is given with mana, like the decision of choice of food item is given by mana.

Comment: Man is a common word for Mind. But more specifically it refers to the emotional aspect of the Mind. Whereas Buddhi, refers to the intellect, or the aspect of the mind that does discrimination (Viveka) and analyzes everything, for example, let's say you get 100% in your exams. Then your Man, will be elated and pumped up that 'Yay I got 100%, I am finally getting what I want'. The Buddhi will analyze as follows 'What is the knowledge I have gained out of it'. However in broad sense, everything is from Mind. i.e. All of creation is a projection of Man or Mind. All the best sir, good q.

Comment: @Rickross Although Budha is the son of Candra. But technically, buddhi precedes manas. That's the very basic siddhānta of Sāṅkhya, which is accepted even in Vedānta. Buddhi -> ahaṅkāra -> 11 indriyas (including manas) alongwith follow the pañcatanmātras and then pañcamahābhūtas.
And this order is accepted even in Bhagavad Gītā (3.42), where buddhi precedes manas. Buddhi itself governs saṅkalpa, which is the funtion of manas. So, buddhi is not born from manas.

Comment: You can check my answer for more detail @Rickross https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/57073/24460

Comment: Thanks for the link @Bingming

Comment: One command misunderstanding is that Man/Buddhi/Chitt/Ahankara are physically different things. All these are part of our consciousness (technically known as Antakarna - meaning inner tools of knowledge) - when it is contemplating it is Man, when deciding things it is Buddhi, when thinking of things it is Chitt and a constant underlying feeling of “I am” is Ahankara.

Answer (score 10):

From [Katha Upanishad](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe15/sbe15012.htm) 3.10-13

> 3. Know the **Self to be sitting in the chariot, the body to be the chariot, the intellect (buddhi) the charioteer, and the mind the
>      reins.**
> 4. The senses they call the horses, the objects of the senses their roads. When he (the Highest Self) is in union with the body, the
>      senses, and the mind, then wise people call him the Enjoyer.
> 5. Beyond the senses there are the objects, beyond the objects there is the mind, **beyond the mind there is the intellect**, the Higher
>      Self(individual soul) is beyond the intellect.'
> 6. 'Beyond the Higher self there is the Unmanifest, beyond the Unmanifest there is the Purusha/Brahman. Beyond the Purusha
>      there is nothing--this is the goal, the highest road.'

From Anu Geeta

> Since the mind is ruler of these five elements, in (the matter of)
>   absorbing or bringing (them) forth, the mind itself is the individual
>   self. The mind always presides over the great elements. The
>   understanding(Buddhi) proclaims its power, and it is called the
>   Kshetrajña. The mind yokes the senses as a charioteer (yokes) good
>   horses. The senses, the mind, and the understanding are always joined
>   to the Kshetrajña. That individual self, mounting the chariot to which
>   big horses are yoked, and in which the understanding is the drag,
>   drives about on all sides the great chariot which is pervaded by the
>   Purusha/Brahman, has the group of the senses yoked (to it), has the
>   mind for a charioteer, and the understanding for a drag. That learned
>   and talented person verily, who always understands thus the chariot
>   pervaded by the Brahman, comes not by delusion in the midst of all
>   entities. This forest of the Brahman begins with the unperceived, and
>   ends with the gross objects; and includes movables and immovables,
>   receives light from the radiance of the sun and moon, is adorned with
>   planets and nakshatras, and is decked on all sides with nets of rivers
>   and mountains, and always beautified likewise by various (descriptions
>   of) waters; it is (the means of) subsistence for all entities, and it
>   is the goal of all living creatures. In this the Kshetrajña always
>   moves about.

Mind(Mann), Intelligence(Buddhi), Chitta, Ego(Ahamkaar) are part of subtle body/ling sharir and tied to individual soul also called causal body/karan sharir.

Answer (score 5):

There seems to be lot of different thoughts regarding *Mann* and *Buddhi*, hence expressing another aspect of it. In nutshell from [BG-3.42]:

> *(Sthula) Shariara < Indriya < **Mann < Buddhi**    < Atman/Brahman* <sub>Sanskrit</sub>
>   *(Physical) Body   < Senses  < **Mind < Intellect** < (True) Self/Soul* <sub>English</sub>

This is how the relation between [Pancha-Kosha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panchakosha#Manomayakosha) & *Atman* is believed:

> *Annamayakosha < PrAnamayakosha < **Mano/VignAna-mayakosha < Anandamayakosha / KArana Sharira** < Atman*
>   <sub>Note: Mano & VignAna are merged to make sense with earlier mapping.</sub>

---

From above 2 sources, it's clear that *Buddhi* should be superior layer of *Mann*. Now we can interpret this in various ways. What I believe is:

***Mann* (Mind)** is a subtle form of brain which goes beyond the physical death. Probably it carries the impressions of desires or *Karma* (action)s generated by Senses. When *Indriya*s are involved in *Karma*, they generate good or bad fruits/*phala*. *Mann* in its form should remain until these fruits are absorbed or the *Indriya*s are gratified in good/bad way. After that *Mann* should go away, i.e. replaced.
Does that mean, end of birth and death? Not mostly.

***Buddhi* (Intellect)** still remains. That's why it's also called *KArana Sharira* (Causal body). This is the root of our existence. This is the last layer of *MAyA*. It's also called *Ananda Sharira*, because it's "Enjoyer" (or "Consumer") of everything. Once this goes, it's all Moksha.
When we watch a movie, our brain gets frightened, sad, romantic, aggressive, patriotic ... depending on contents. But from inside we know that, it's all imagination. Still we have a cause to consume & enjoy. In this analogy, your "Inside" is *Buddhi* which controls your "Brain" or *Mann*.

---

> "So who differentiates all these: *Sharira, Indriya, Mann, Buddhi, Atman*?"

I call this differentiator as "Consciousness" or *"ChetanA"*. In other words, what is called "I", is *ChetanA*. This might be a subtle aspect of *SagunA Brahman*[BG 10.22].
The controller is decided based on where this *ChetanA* is residing. For various aspects of life, this *ChetanA* may reside at different levels as listed above. According to which level constitutes *ChetanA*, the various *Buddhi*s are differentiated.

When *ChetanA* resides on:

1. *Sthula Sharira*: The matter is like dead. It can't do anything
   on its own. That's why it's also called *Acheta*.
2. *Indriya*: Animal or animalistic persons (*Jada*) often fall here. They are usually *TAmasic* by nature[BG 18.32]. They just do things for sense
   gratification. While hungry they eat, in season they mate, in
   aggression they scream. They are usually impulsive beings who act in
   *Adharma*, genuinely thinking that to be *Dharma*. Being directionless, they leave in misery. They have *Chetana*, but act like *Acheta*. They don't work for "sense gratification", they are simply "Embodied Senses".
3. ***Mann***: *RAjasic* people fall here[BG 18.31]. Those who are conscious by *Mann* are not under control of *Indriya*s, but try to gratify it. In other words, their *Karma*s are influenced by *Indriya*s. This is where actual *Adharma* resides. Their *Karma*s are termed as good
   or bad and 'apparently' generate the fruits. Humans with desires
   would act according to their *Mann*. Though their *Chetana* is in *Mann*, they act as of it's in above categories.
4. ***Buddhi***: This is the place where people are fully aware about their own *Dharma* and act accordingly. Their actions might even seem like
   all above categories, but their consciousness is alive. Such people
   also are not bound by *Karma*s. These are *SAtvika* beings[BG 18.30],
   nearer to god, but not yet liberated. Everything for them is blissful
   as they consider *Sukha* (happiness) and *Dukha* (sadness) as same.
   For them there is NO enough reason to move beyond. Hence they keep
   enjoying until the *Moksha* happens. These beings have realized that, all actions are happening on their own, there is no ownership.
   Probably that's why such *SAtvika* beings are called *Buddha* (from *Buddhi*) and they have a valid reason for saying "nothing" is supreme beyond this.
5. *Atman*: This is that "nothing" (*Nirguna Brahman*), which is transcendental to all above. It's void of all above. There is neither *Dharma* nor *Adharma*. It's *Moksha*, the ultimate state.

All above are described in purest form. But everything is more or less present in the most beings.

---

> <sub>BG 3.42 — Senses are said to be beyond (to body), Mind is beyond Senses, Intellect is even beyond Mind, "That" (*Nirguna Brahman*) is even beyond Intellect.</sub>
>   <sub>BG 10.22 — Among VedAs I am SAma Veda, among demigods I am VAsava, To the Senses I am Mind and within material manifestations I am ChetaNa.</sub>
>   <sub>BG 18.30 — The one who knows activity & retirement, duty & non-duty, fear & boldness and bonding & liberation properly, has *SAtvika Buddhi*.</sub>
>   <sub>BG 18.31 — The one who doesn't know *Dharma & Adharma*, duty & non-duty as it is, has *RAjasi Buddhi*.</sub>
>   <sub>BG 18.32 — Covered by darkness (*Tamas*), the one who believes *Adharma* as *Dharma* and believes other (thing)s also wrongly, has *TAmasi Buddhi*.</sub>
>   <sub>--from Gita press, Gorakhpur</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Atma is the most Powerful which controls Buddhi.
Budhi is more Powerful and should control and guide the Mann for decision making. Mann is more Powerful than Indriya (sense organs).

Atma is the supreme power, Ideally!, Buddhi should surrender to Atma, Buddhi should control the Mann and Mann should control Indriya.

Mann needs awareness to control the Indriya. The "Control" directly proportional to the "Awareness".

-Bhagvad Geeta,
Adhay 3, Shlok 42

Answer (score 2):

The Sanskrit word Yoga has its literal root “yuj”, meaning, to join, to unite, or, to attach. One who practices Yoga is a Yogi or Yogini. The form of YogA which originated in ancient India is practiced as a combination of physical, mental, and spiritual processes for disciplining one’s BMCA (Budhi, Manas, Chitta, Ahankara) fit enough to steer the Mantra practioners-upasakas-- forward  (Sangeetha, Namasankeertana   suffused with bakthi are also Mantras more so in Kaliyuga).  The term Yoga refers to both the goal and the method of attaining it through an array of paths, schools, principles and practices. It prescribes techniques for continuous purification of the body-mind complex, to still the extraneous noises and prepare the individual to resonate with Cosmic Intellect (CI) contained in Akasa, to tap it for benevolent use. Yoga and Mantras are pure in that, they handhold the actioners to develop linkages with Consciousness, to download continuously enlarging and uplifting the horizon of spiritual insights. As such yogic cleansing of one’s BMCA. Is the essential minimum requirement for GM to handhold. Reference to GM includes all Mantras as She is the controller of it all as we shall see later.
Viewed superficially, the goals of different Yogic forms are different. There is however a serious commonality between systems, as also lasting goals like, concentration, devotion and character development ethical, austere role of living  and all. As such, Yogic forms cover a broad spectrum of approaches. Yoga helps the creative use of the emotions, curbing particularly those which are distractive, disruptive and destructive. It creates large heartedness, a breadth of vision, and weeds out narrow-mindedness, promotes intuitive/ creative prowess, friendliness, compassion, empathy, and finally prepares him to serve nature its beings and its other entities without selfishness but with abundant endearing care.  It promotes also the health, wellness and the aspirations of the practioners-sadakas- to serve better. Rishis/ NYs   are such standing examples. it is apt to draw the mythological ego problem of who is greater, Raja rishi Viswamitra or the Maharishi Vasishta and finally it is Vasishta with the power of mantras easily won over Viswamitra and his huge army and   blessed the other confirming the power of Rishis.
Maharishi Patanjali In his Ashtanga Yoga – The Moksha Ladder prescribed (about 5000 BC) eight steps: to achieve such an extraordinary cleansing of mind and body in a stage by stage manner as outlined below:
Yama aims at internal   purification or moral code,  Niyama aims at external purity or personal discipline, Asana consists in the performance of the postures of Yoga,  Pranayama is breath control, Pratyahara results from the withdrawal of sense organs  Dharana is concentration,  Dhyana is meditation, Samadhi is the final state of spiritual absorption
The first five steps are the preliminaries promoting samanya (normal) dharma that elevates the personality of individuals. For a Sanyasi aspiring Moksha, the Nivritti Margi, all the eight limbs are essential, whereas for the householder practicing Pravritti Marga, the first five limbs are deemed sufficient. No necessity to become a sanyasi. And that is why it is said that most of us with little more discipline can become Privritti margis, 
The most difficult part of Yoga however, is control of the body and mind. The Tamil philosopher-saint Thayyumanavar (1705–1742) says: "It is easy to control an elephant, catch hold of the tiger's tail, grab the snake and dance, dictate the angels, transmigrate into another body, walk on water or sit on the sea; but it is difficult to control the mind and remain quiet”. But Yoga and GM can lead you to achieve these

Budhi, it is said, has 3 children, Manas, Chitta and Ahankara-If these children get cultivated and obey budhi, and then one can become a great Rishi or Scientist et al. If not one has all the qualifications to become a rakshasa.  So one of the main goals and aims of Yoga is to make these children obey budhi. Why budhi? Sciences now support that divine instructions are being received only by budhi from Akasa through Nonlocalaction, Morphic resonance/ templates,(outlined elsewhere) et al. Gayatri had confirmed this way back saying NAHA DHEEHI PRACHODAYAT. Pl note, NAHA means OUR and not MINE alone, bringing out the significance of Collective Consciousness and DHEEHI means Budhi and not mind
The concept of yuj to unite can be expanded to cover various other beneficial areas such as: a-uniting quarrelling people, groups, and nations;  b— restoring the health of any biological entity  since  its healthy life is due to countless cells of the body functioning  in symphony but if dissonance sets in the body is diseased .   Uniting the dissonant with harmonius rest is also Yoga c- non equitable sharing or wasting natures resources etc are amenable for yogic cure. Generalising, where ever chos or dishormy prevails ie if Entropy of a system increases Yoga can play its beneficial role. And many yogic schools are alredy trying to cover such areas.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE. Can you please cite references in your answer as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The word 'मन' in Hindī is derived from the technical Sanskrit term 'मनस्' (manas). 
Both manas & buddhi are explained in a succinct manner in Īśvarakr̥ṣṇa's Sāṅkhyakārikā (v. 23, 27)

> adhyavasāyo buddhirdharmo jñānaṁ virāga aiśvaryam / 
> sāttvikametadrupaṁ tāmasamasmādviparyastam // (23)

*Buddhi is adhyavasāya (niścaya). Dharma, jñāna, vairāgya, & aiśvarya constitutes its sāttvika rūpa, while each of their opposites (adharma, ajñāna, avairāgya, & anaiśvarya) constitutes its tāmasa rūpa.*

> abhimāno'haṅkārastasmād dvividhaḥ pravartate sargaḥ / 
> ekādaśakaśca gaṇastanmātrapañcakaścaiva // (24)

*Abhimāna is ahaṅkāra; thence proceeds twofold utpatti of sr̥ṣṭi. the (first) set of ekādaśa(11) indriyas and the (second) pañca (5) tanmātras.*

> ubhayātmakamatra manaḥ saṅkalpakamindiyam ca sādharmyāt /
> guṇapariṇāmaviśeṣannānāvataṁ bāhyabhedaśca // (27)

*Of these (11 indriyas), manas is ubhayātmaka (jñāna-karmendriyātmaka). It's the agent of saṅkalpa (both saṅkalpa & vikalpa) and due to being sādharmyāt (having same dharmabhāva) as indriyas, it's also called an indriya. Through guṇapariṇāmabheda (pariṇāmabheda of guṇas), various indriyas are born, similar to how variety (bheda) of bāhyatanmātras, etc. is caused due to guṇapariṇāma-bheda.*

> mūlaprakr̥tiravikr̥tirmahadādyāḥ prakr̥tivikr̥tayaḥ sapta / 
> ṣoḍaśakastu vikāro na prakr̥tirna vikr̥tiḥ puruṣaḥ // (3)

*Mūlaprakr̥ti is avikr̥ta (without any vikāra) ; mahat (buddhi), etc. 7 tattvas are both prakr̥ti (kāraṇa) & vikr̥ti (vikāra) ;the set of 16 tattvas are [merely] vikāra ; puruṣa is neither prakr̥ti nor vikr̥ti.*

So, manas is merely vikr̥ti & not prakr̥ti while buddhi (mahat) is both vikr̥ti & prakr̥ti because latter's the kāraṇotpatti of ahaṅkāra, etc. This is a key difference b/w buddhi & manas.

As per Bhagavad Gītā (3.42), buddhi is superior to manas

> indriyāṇi parāṇyāhurindriyēbhyaḥ paraṁ manaḥ / 
> manasastu parā buddhiryō buddhēḥ paratastu saḥ //

Madhusūdana Sarasvatī in his commentary Gūḍhārthadīpikā to this śloka says, "manasastu parā buddhiradhyavasāyātmikā ; adhyavasāyo hi niścayastatpūrvaka eva saṅkalpādirmanodharmaḥ" i.e. adhyavasāyātmikā buddhi is śreṣṭha to manas because niścaya is called adhyavasāya and doing saṅkalpa, etc. tattvapūrvaka (niścayapūrvaka) is the dharma of manas. So, buddhi precedes manas.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is kinda yogic and philosophical/spiritual one.

Prakriti in our body has 8 forms.: These are Pancha Tattvas and Mann, Buddhi, Ahamkara.

BG. 7.4.:

> “Earth, water, fire, air, ether, mind (Manas) and intellect (Buddhi), egoism (Ahamkara),–thus hath my nature (Prakriti) been divided eight-fold”.

Where, Mind is related to Moon, Ahamkara to Lightning and Buddhi to Sun.

Basically, As Prakriti, in our inner cosmos they represent the senses and similarly, their Purusha counter part represents the [Ashta-Murti](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/satapatha-brahmana-english/d/doc63292.html) elements in Outer cosmos.

- Earth = Pashupati.
- Water = Sarva.
- Fire = Rudra.
- Air = Ugra.
- Ether = Bhava.
- Mind (Moon) = Mahadeva.
- Buddhi (Sun) = Ishana.
- Ahamkara (Lightning) = Asani.

As, Manas remains uncontrolled. It becomes the source of Avidya or Evil. Negative thoughts are the products of Mind only. So, Mind creates our Inner demon Vritra.

Satapatha Brahmana 1:6:4:13.:

> “An offering in honour of the Vritra-slayer, then, is the full-moon sacrifice. **Vritra, assuredly, is no other than the moon;** and when during that night (of new moon) he is not seen either in the east or in the west, then he (Indra) completely destroys him by means of that (new-moon sacrifice), and leaves nothing remaining of him. **And, verily, he who knows this, overcomes all evil and leaves nothing remaining of evil”.**

And by Intellect/Knowledge, the inner demons are slain.

Mandala Brahmana Upanishad - 5.:

> **"The Manas influenced by worldly objects is liable to bondage; and that (Manas) which is not so influenced by these is fit for salvation. Hence the entire world becomes an object of Chitta; whereas the same Chitta when it is supportless and well-ripe in the state of Unmani, becomes worthy of Laya (absorption in Brahman).** This absorption you should learn from me who am the all-full. **I (Sun/Knowledge/Buddhi) alone am the cause of the absorption of Manas.** The Manas is within the Jyotis (spiritual light) which again is latent in the spiritual sound which pertains to the Anahata (heart) sound. **That Manas which is the agent of creation, preservation and destruction of the three worlds - that same Manas becomes absorbed in that which is the highest seat of Vishnu”.**

Note.: Chitta is the 9th form of Prakriti and all the 8th Prakritis are a Product of Chitta. It's Purusha equivalent is Kumara. And these 9 forms are called (9÷3) 3 folds of Agni/Gayatri.

Conclusion.: Thus, Manas is the agent of Maya (Creation, Preservation, Destruction) and Through the Intellect/Brahma Vidya (Buddhi) one can get Param Gati Moksha.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Comment: This is a very good perspective. Unfortunately, the interpretation of the same in dualistic philosophy is not very popular. +1.

Comment: Bro what i think is... It doesn't matter if the fact is popular or unpopular but the fact will remain a fact only. One can agree or disagree. Anyways,  i m not saying them wrong but **for me** it's just lower stages of the same knowledge that's it. .. +1...

Answer (score 1):

Here are the precise "definitions" of Buddhi and Manas from Vedantasara.

> The subtle bodies are what are known as the Linga-Sariras having
> seventeen component parts. The component parts (of the Linga-Sarira)
> are the five organs of perception, **the intellect, the mind**, the
> five organs of action, and the five vital forces. **Intellect (Buddhi)
> is that modification of the internal instrument (Antahkarana) which
> determines (the real nature of an object)**.  The mind **(Manas) is
> that modification of the internal instrument which considers the pros
> and cons of a subject** (Sankalpa and Vikalpa).The mind-stuff (Chitta)
> and egoism (Ahamkara) are included in the intellect (Buddhi) and the
> mind (Manas) respectively.Memory (Chitta) is that modification of the
> inner organ which remembers.Egoism (Ahamkara) is that modification of
> the inner organ which is characterised by Self-consciousness. **This
> intellect (Buddhi) together with the organs of perception constitutes
> the intelligent sheath (Vijnanamayakosa)**.This Vijnanamayakosa, on
> account of its being conscious that it is an agent and enjoyer and
> that it is happy or miserable etc., is called the phenomenal Jiva (the
> individual self) subject to transmigration to this and the other
> worlds. (Vedantasara 65-73)

Answer (score 1):

One command misunderstanding is that Man/Buddhi/Chitt/Ahankara are physically different things. All these are part of our consciousness (technically known as Antakarna - meaning inner tools of knowledge) - when it is contemplating it is Man, when deciding things it is Buddhi, when thinking of things it is Chitt and a constant underlying feeling of “I am” is Ahankara.

Answer (score 0):

```
           Mind Vs Buddhi
```

MANO VAACHAHA BUDDHISCHA BEDHAHA

What we may think in mind cant be spoken. What is good for listener must only be spoken. This is the difference.

Mind is powerful than languages but language(by Buddhi) can protect human.

```
           3 MINDS
```

Mind differs for humans in 3 ways

1. Mind that is flawed - Taamasika mind which is doubtful & always indecisive abiding dictator. They wait for other mind to do an action/ new thought do that the Taamasika may copy the actions/thoughts, but unfortunately even after copying minds they may doubt the credibility of actions. These are minds of sinners.
2. Mind that is outflown - Raagaatmika (excessively exhibitory & action based). The minds have excessive attachment towards human lives without knowing how humans originate. Sometimes they go negatively depressed to inhibit human values.
3. Mind that is clear & pervading Earth's layers - Anaamika
   This mind has no much commitment towards others and may think less or only if required. It can energise soul.

   ```
          TRAPPED HUMANs
   ```

Though 3 different minds exist, their discourse depends on Pitruloka - the loka of offerings accepted by ancestors combined with humans with 3 types of minds form a closed TRAP of "Janma Mrutyu Vyadhi Bhayam" etc.

This TRAP is opened up only when Pitruun attain God and humans realise the "power of discrimination of good & bad" called BUDDHIHI.

Throughout history Tamasika & Raagaatmikas impacted & suppressed Anaamikas to stop PITRULOKA souls reaching God thinking that powerful souls may take rebirth from PITRULOKA in some other community than existing Anaamikaas. This greed or jealous nature produced no Anamikaas in other communities but more DISABLED children.

```
         AAGAMASAARAM
```

(free mind of required intellect)

To hide the fact that children are DISABLED more schools are modernised where group behaviour determines individual score in a class than "an individual merit earned by an individual".
Hence, result is a big human TRAP of less intellectual freedom.

The ONSET OF SWAMI VEDANTA DESIKAN
described the waste TRAP (VIPHALAAHA) referring to "Paancharaathra Aagama".

Mind though powerful than Intellect acquired, in KaliYuga the minds from genes of humans from waste TRAP over generations is very shallow and subjected to "futile actions" thus requiring AAGAMA to create "freedom to mind with minimum intellect".