# Scripture to learn about manas, chitta, ahamkar and buddhi in detail?

Tags: scripture, mind, buddhi

Is there an authentic ancient scripture to study about manas, ahamkar, buddhi, chitta, chit, chit vritti etc. in detail, so one can exactly know what they are and how they differ?
For example, to study Sanskrit there's well structured Ashtadhyayi, to study how to pronounce sounds of Sanskrit alphabets there's Shiksha granth. Similarly, where can I learn about the terms I mentioned above?

Comment: Related https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10784/what-is-the-difference-between-buddhi-%E0%A4%AC%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A7%E0%A4%BF-and-mann-%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%A8

Comment: Don't know about authentic scripture it may be Samkhya. Btw, Swami Vivekananda's [Rajayoga](https://ramakrishnavivekananda.info/vivekananda/volume_1/raja-yoga/raja-yoga_contents.htm) is helpful in understanding these terms.

Comment: @AkshayKumarS I saw your edited the question by replacing "Samskrit" with Sanskrit. I have no problem with it. But want to know why you preferred the later if you don't mind.