# Comparison of contributions of manas and buddhi in attaining moksha

Tags: moksha, mind, buddhi

Across the Scriptures of sanathan dharma, a [particular classification](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10784/what-is-the-difference-between-buddhi-%E0%A4%AC%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A7%E0%A4%BF-and-mann-%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%A8) is as follows:

> Universe/world, Senses of body, manas, buddhi, and para brahman.

One needs to attain para brahman, which is generally called moksha. Buddhi can be viewed as the container of intelligence or knowledge useful for attaining moksha. Mahavakyas is then enough for buddhi. The key task is then to stabilize manas on para brahman using buddhi.

In this context, Can I say that the contribution of manas is more than the contribution of Buddhi for attaining moksha?

Or am I wrong anywhere? If wrong then how Buddhi need to contribute more than manas for attaining moksha?

Comment: Please put the source of the classification quote. You may also want to define the terms  mãnas(मानस) and buddhi (बुद्धि) properly in your question itself to get an understanding of your doubts properly perhaps

Comment: @Vivikta if you did like the question maybe you can contribute an upvote since we are anyway trying to increase voting on the site. Hanuman asks really intriguing questions.

Comment: @Archit  - " Liking a question and thus Up voting it", "trying to correct unambiguous language in a question to make it more likeable maybe", & "Hãnuman",  are three totally different scenarios, :P :))

Comment: @Vivikta I added the classification requested. Thanks...

Comment: @hanugm - as per the added classifications' answers, it becomes clear that, intellect i.e., buddhi (बुद्धि) presides over the manas, mind (मन - मानस). In that way it's the last sheath to be crossed to realize our true nature as an atman which may or may not be identical with the Paramātman (depending on the School of Thought, we might be dealing with). Which is greater or lesser, becomes how we perceive the Reality.

Comment: @Vivikta yeah, but which one has to contribute more to realize para brahman and why?

Comment: One peels off each layer of avidya (अविद्या) one by one. Until the layer being worked upon is peeled off its the most important, as soon as it's peeled off, the succeeding layer of avidya is the most important. This process of peeling each layer one by one, shall repeat until we realize our only true nature of - *sat-chitt-ananda*, that's when all forms of avidya ceases to exist. So, importance depending more upon where (layer of avidya) are we on, in our journey of Enlightenment.