# Is OBE or Astral projection real ? is there any reference to it in any?

Tags: puranas

i would likely to know is there any reference in any of  Purana about OBE or Astral projection

Comment: What is OBE and Astral Projection?

Comment: My answer here may help you: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6524/are-there-references-to-out-of-body-experiences-in-hinduism-or-its-texts-in-deta/11186#11186

Comment: @Yogi Out-of-body experience (OBE).