# What is the meaning of 'fifth' in the following shloka?

Tags: vedas, upanishads, brahman, katha-upanishad

> भयद्सग्निस्तपति भयात्तपति सूर्यः ||
>
> भयादिन्द्रश्च वायुश्च मृतुर्धावति पञ्चम: ||३||

Kathopanishad Chapter 2 valli (shloka/verse) 3

Meaning:

> From fear of bramhan fire burns, from fear(of bramhan) the sun shines, from fear Indra, Vayu, Death, and the fifth, run.

What I think 'The fifth' means :

The fifth element here might represent, Akasha (Ether/space) because agni(fire), vayu(air) are explicitly mentioned and from Indra -> varuna (water) is indirectly  mentioned and bhoomi (earth) cannot run.
So this is what I conclude on basis of  omnipotence and importance of akasha element.

I think there is more to `the fifth` in this verse, so I ask you(reader) to convince and prove(with literature) meaning of `"The Fifth"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The meaning is much simpler than that: the fifth refers to Death.  [Here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe15/sbe15015.htm) is what the verse says:

> From terror of Brahman fire burns, from terror the sun burns, from terror Indra and Vâyu, and Death, as the fifth, run away.

The verse is listing five things: fire, the Sun, Indra, Vayu, and Death.  So all it's saying is that Death is the fifth item in the list.

Adi Shankaracharya says the same thing in [this excerpt](http://gdurl.com/IJoV) from his commentary on the Katha Upanishad:

> How the world lives from fear, of him, is explained. The fire burns from fear of him, the lord of all; the sun shines from fear; from fear, Indra and Wind; **and Death, the fifth, runs**; for, if Brahman did not exist as controller of the competent protectors of the world, like one with the thunderbolt 
>   uplifted in his hand, their well-regulated activity, as that of the servants trembling from fear of the master would not be possible.

By the way, on a side note, in this verse Yama is actually paraphrasing a quote from [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe15/sbe15041.htm) of the Taittiriya Upanishad.

Comment: why is same thing repeated in Taittiriya Upanishad? Adi Shankara's Commentry is awesome! :D thanx for a good commentry

Comment: @Creator The Taittiriya Upanishad already existed at the time of Nachiketa, so Yama is just paraphrasing an existing source of wisdom.  (Although even the Taittiriya Upanishad introduces it by [saying](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe15/sbe15040.htm)  "On this there is also this Sloka", so maybe the Taittiriya Upanishad is quoting an even older source...)  By the way, to give you a rough idea of the chronology of the Upanishads, the Isha Upanishad is timeless (because it's part of the Yajur Veda Samhita).  Then comes the trio of Brihadaranyaka, Taittiriya, and Chandogya.

Comment: @Creator In fact, Vyasa's original purpose in composing the Brahma Sutras was to show that the Brihadaranyaka, Taittiriya and Chandogya Upanishads are consistent with one another.  In any case, after that comes the Kena Upanishad and then the other [Mukhya Upanishads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mukhya_Upanishads), and then after that the rest of the Upanishads.

Comment: @Creator By the way, here are Adi Shankaracharya's commentaries on other Upanishads: http://hinduebooks.blogspot.com/2010/11/principal-upanishads-with-shankara.html Note that they're written from the perspective of Advaita, so you might want to also read commentaries written from other perspectives, like Visistadvaita.

Comment: Isha upanishad literally means from Ishan (bramhan) ishwara?? that is why it is considered untouched by human nature??

Comment: @Creator No, the name of the Isha Upanishad doesn't signify anything about its origins.  Its actual name is the Vajasaneyi Samhita Upanishad, because the Samhita of the Shukla Yajur Veda is called the Vajasaneyi Samhita, but it's referred to as the Isha Upanishad because its opening verse begins with the word "Ishavasyam", meaning covered by the Lord.  By the way, Gandhi said that if the entire Hindu religion were destroyed and only one thing could be saved, he would save the first verse.  Here is a beautiful discussion about the first verse: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJOpV0PvfvY

Comment: @Creator I think Gandhi just meant "if humans completely forgot about Sanatana Dharma".  But yeah, the Isha Upanishad is part of the Samhitas of the Vedas, so it consists of mantras heard directly from the gods, not conversations between human teachers and students like other Upanishads.  I still haven't confirmed which Rishi heard the Isha Upanishad from the gods, though, which is why I asked this question: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2826/36