# How does Advaita interpret the devatas to the Isha Upanishad mantras?

Tags: gods, mantras, upanishads, atma, advaita

Advaita is a non dual philosophy which says there is no distinction between Jivatma and Paramatma (Brahman). There is only one soul which is Brahman.

In the Isha Upanishad or Ishavasyopanishad which is a part of Vajasaneyi samhita, there are mantras to whom the devata is Atma.

The devata of the mantras 1 to 14 and 17 is **Atma**. The devatas of the mantra 15 are both **Paramatma and Atma**. (More details about the mantras in [Who is the seer of the Isha Upanishad?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14443/5212)). Now, the devatas are said as Atma and paramatma differently.

Advaita and non dual philosophies claim no difference between atma and Paramatma. How do they interpret the devatas to the mantras of Isha Upanishad?

Comment: Atman looking for Paramatman (realization of true self). The difference holds until realization, after realization, no difference.

Comment: @Pandya Even the devatas of the mantras are under the maya and unrealised?

Comment: "no distinction between Jivatma and Paramatma (Brahman)" Only at Paramarthika level not at vyavaharika or phenomenal world. World is real for us but not real for realized in simple words.

Comment: @TheDestroyer These mantras are heard by the rishi who is at highest level. How can a realised rishi speak of unrealised soul or Atma. What about the 17th mantra? It is said to both Atma and Paramatma. How can they both coexist? It is either Atma o Paramatma. Right?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma We need to correlate "Advaitic state of realization" to "deep tapasya state" of Rishis to understand this better. Let me search.

Comment: Rishi means Mantradrasta, not necessarily a realised soul who is one with brahma. Devata means someone who is shining. So Krishna (Who is Paramatma) and Indra both are referred to as Devata. So why the Atmaa and Paramatmaa will always be identical ?